# Why can't I push to this bare repository?

Tags: git

Can you explain what is wrong with this workflow?

```
$ git init --bare bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /work/fun/git_experiments/bare/
$ git clone bare alice
Cloning into alice...
done.
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
$ cd alice/
$ touch a
$ git add a
$ git commit -m "Added a"
[master (root-commit) 70d52d4] Added a
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 a
$ git push
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to '/work/fun/git_experiments/bare'
```

Doesn't `git push` always push to the repository I cloned from?

Comment: Shouldn't you specify branch to push?

Comment: not after a clone!!!  after the problem is fixed, it works great and no need to specify the branch...just on this first checkout of an empty repository does this occur which is VERY VERY annoying...they should fix this issue.

Comment: Hope this post would be useful to somebody when trying to do above- http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/07/create-git-bitbucket-repository-from.html?view=sidebar  The error in the question can be popped even when tried to Create a git BitBucket repository from an already locally existing project

Answer (score 487, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that there are no commits in "bare".  This is a problem with the first commit only, if you create the repos in the order (bare,alice).  Try doing:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

This would only be required the first time.  Afterwards it should work normally.

As Chris Johnsen pointed out, you would not have this problem if your push.default was customized.  I like upstream/tracking.

Comment: I'm doing `sudo apt-get upgrade git-core` and `sudo apt-get upgrade git` and it think no update is necessary. `git --version` returns 1.7.3.1. Any idea what's missing? I admit currently `apt-get update` doesn't work for me, but it did not too long ago.

Comment: @ripper234: The current version of git is 1.7.5.3  You can either live with the inconvenience, use a different workflow, or install the latest git manually w/o debian/ubuntu packaging.

Comment: Ah right, I forget that software take some time before it gets packaged. I'm a linux noob, coming from Windows, and used to click-here-to-install-the-newest-version.

Comment: Regarding “Recent version don't have this problem”: Even in recent versions, the default for pushes does not seem to have changed from `matching`; maybe you have `push.default` set to `upstream`/`tracking` (or `current`) in your `~/.gitconfig`?

Comment: @Chris Johnsen: Good catch.  I always forget that the default isn't tracking since I have had that set ever since I started using git several years ago and it seems so sane.

Comment: @SethRobertson  When I run your command, I get the following error: error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:username/myproject.git'

Comment: Try `git push origin master:master` to make it explicit.  If that doesn't work, check to see what branch you are on: `git branch` perhaps you have not made the first commit or you made that commit on a branch other than master.

Comment: @Igor Ganapolsky: Previous comment was directed at you.  This present just for notification purposes (will edits cause notifications?)

Comment: In later versions of Git, this syntax is a little more terse: `git push -u origin master`. It pushes "master" to origin and sets up remote tracking.

Comment: Hope this post would be useful to somebody- http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/07/create-git-bitbucket-repository-from.html?view=sidebar  The error in the question can be popped even when tried to Create a git BitBucket repository from an already locally existing project

Comment: This doesn't work.  "error: src refspec origin does not match any."

Comment: @pabrams Did you see the dup comment above and my reply giving a more specific command that seems to be sometimes necessary (depending on your push.default setting).

Answer (score 42):

If you:

```
 git push origin master
```

it will push to the bare repo.

It sounds like your alice repo isn't tracking correctly.

```
cat .git/config
```

This will show the default remote and branch.

If you

```
 git push -u origin master
```

You should start tracking that remote and branch. I'm not sure if that option has always been in git.

Answer (score 33):

This related question's answer provided the solution for me... it was just a dumb mistake:

Remember to commit first!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252

If you have not yet committed to your local repo, there is nothing to push, but the Git error message you get back doesn't help you too much.

Answer (score 19):

```
git push --all
```

is the canonical way to push everything to a new bare repository.

Another way to do the same thing is to create your new, non-bare repository and then make a bare clone with

```
git clone --bare
```

then use

```
git remote add origin <new-remote-repo>
```

in the original (non-bare) repository.

Comment: ...so you downvoted the answer? It _is_ the standard way to push everything to a new, bare repository. If it didn't work for you, there is some other issue.

Comment: You're right, I probably shouldn't have, I know you were just trying to help. If you edit it I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: Thanks, edited it with another way to accomplish the same task.

Comment: Your answer helped me thanks ;) But at the end of the command, the path must be present like this: `git push --all ../test_repo` the repo's URL at the end of the command ;)

Comment: @Metafaniel That depends on how you set it up. If your local repo already has the remote properly configured, "git push --all" should work as is.

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your `alice` repository (before pushing):

```
git config push.default tracking
```

Or, configure it as the default for your user with `git config --global …`.

---

`git push` does default to the `origin` repository (which is normally the repository from which you cloned the current repository), but it does not default to pushing the current branch—it defaults to pushing only branches that exist in both the source repository and the destination repository.

The `push.default` configuration variable (see [*git-config(1)*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)) controls what `git push` will push when it is not given any “refspec” arguments (i.e. something after a repository name). The default value gives the behavior described above.

Here are possible values for `push.default`:

- `nothing`
  This forces you to supply a “refspec”.
- `matching` (the default)
  This pushes *all* branches that exist in both the source repository and the destination repository.
  This is completely independent of the branch that is currently checked out.
- `upstream` or `tracking`
  (Both values mean the same thing. The later was deprecated to avoid confusion with “remote-tracking” branches. The former was introduced in 1.7.4.2, so you will have to use the latter if you are using Git 1.7.3.1.)
  These push the current branch to the branch specified by its “upstream” configuration.
- `current`
  This pushes the current branch to the branch of the same name at the destination repository.

  These last two end up being the same for common cases (e.g. working on local *master* which uses *origin/master* as its upstream), but they are different when the local branch has a different name from its “upstream” branch:

  ```
  git checkout master
  # hack, commit, hack, commit

  # bug report comes in, we want a fix on master without the above commits

  git checkout -b quickfix origin/master  # "upstream" is master on origin
  # fix, commit
  git push
  ```

  With `push.default` equal to `upstream` (or `tracking`), the push would go to `origin`’s *master* branch. When it is equal to `current`, the push would go to `origin`’s *quickfix* branch.

The `matching` setting will update `bare`’s *master* in your scenario once it has been established. To establish it, you could use `git push origin master` once.

However, the `upstream` setting (or maybe `current`) seems like it might be a better match for what you expect to happen, so you might want to try it:

```
# try it once (in Git 1.7.2 and later)
git -c push.default=upstream push

# configure it for only this repository
git config push.default upstream

# configure it for all repositories that do not override it themselves
git config --global push.default upstream
```

(Again, if you are still using a Git before 1.7.4.2, you will need to use `tracking` instead of `upstream`).

Answer (score 1):

I use **SourceTree** git client, and I see that their initial commit/push command is:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags --set-upstream origin master:master
```