# Github Duplicating a repository: fixing remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, github

I am following the following process to duplicate a repository found here:

https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/

1. Create a new private repository (new-repository.git) on github made sure not to create a readme - Done
2. Create a bare clone of the public repository (old-repository.git) I want to duplicate by running

git clone --bare https://github.com/exampleuser/old-repository.git

Success.

3. Then I do this:

cd old-repository.git

And this:

git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git

I then get the error in my terminal that:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git/' not found
```

I seems like I am missing a simple step.  How can I find out what is going wrong and fix it.

Comment: Try pushing to `https://yourusername@github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git` to force git to ask for a password.

Comment: Do you have 2FA activated? (https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/)

Comment: I tried both suggestions above - good suggestions. Thank you.  I turn off 2FA and tried the @robertklep suggestion.  When i add my password I get the following:  "No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
Everything up-to-date"

Comment: The error message "No refs in common..." suggest that there is  step missing.  Some suggestions on SO are to create a master found here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23528761/no-refs-in-common-and-none-specified-doing-nothing    But that is not in the instructions.  In fact you are told not  to create a readme.  Tried anyway and no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new remote to your old repository and push your source to new remote repository.

```
$ cd old-repository
$ git remote add newremote https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git

#pushes specific branch to remote
$ git push newremote some-branch-name

#pushes all branches to remote
$ git push newremote '*:*'

#pushes all tags to remote 
$ git push newremote --follow-tags
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.

Create a new repo in the destination location before you try to push to it.

Don't initialize it with a readme, just create.

Then retry git push --mirror https://github.com/exampleuser/new-repository.git