# Accidentally deleted branch on which repo was based, how to fix?

Tags: git

I have deleted branch on which I was rebased. I was thinking that solution might be to checkout to master and then to fetch remote branch and continue with work, but I get this error,

```
notice: HEAD points to an unborn branch
```

How to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551278/issues-with-git-head-points-to-an-unborn-branch-master

Comment: Can you provide a list of commands and their output that led you to this state?

Comment: The thing was I was on a feature/branch_1 and I did git branch -d feature/branch_1. What I now did is following: As I had only one commit that was not part of remote (simple one) I did git fetch origin feature/branch_1 and add again small commit. But I am wandering if that is not the case, how can I locally restore deleted branch.

Answer (score 3):

Git normally will not *allow* you to delete the branch you're on, for just this sort of reason.

The most fundamental problem here is that the *branch name* contained the commit hash ID.  That is, according to your comment, you did this:

```
git checkout feature/branch_1
```

which put the name `feature/branch_1` into the special name `HEAD`.  The name itself, i.e., `feature/branch_1`, contained the 40-character hash ID of the branch tip, so that the *name* remembered the actual commit hash.

Then you ran:

```
git branch -d feature/branch_1
```

Git should have just said *no, you may not do that*.  (There have been some bugs around this when using `git worktree add`, and there are various ways you can cause yourself problems, but `git branch` itself is *supposed* to just say no here.)  When this succeeded, you were left with:

- `HEAD` contains `feature/branch_1`
- but `feature/branch_1` does not exist.

The way to fix it is to re-create the name `feature/branch_1` while putting the correct commit hash ID into it.  The problem is that there is no memory of which commit hash it should be holding: that hash ID *was* stored under the name `feature/branch_1`, and no longer is.

What you need, then, is some alternative method for finding this hash ID.  One way is that if there is *another* name that *also* stores the correct hash ID, you can read the hash ID from that other name:

```
git branch feature/branch_1 origin/feature/branch_1
```

for instance.  However, if there is no such other name, that won't work.

Fortunately, `HEAD` has a *reflog*, and the `HEAD` reflog stores the raw commit hashes of the commits you have visited.  Unfortunately, in this state it looks like Git refuses to use it:

```
$ git reflog HEAD
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

and:

```
$ git rev-parse HEAD@{0}
HEAD@{0}
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@{0}': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

However, this does the trick:

```
$ tail -1 .git/logs/HEAD | awk '{print $2}'
b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a
```

so you can resort to this particular trick in this particular case (which should otherwise never occur anyway).

Comment: The problem was that git reflog was failing

Comment: Yes, as I noted above, if `HEAD` refers to a nonexistent branch, `git reflog HEAD` fails. But I also showed how to use the reflog to recover the hash ID anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do git reflog and find the SHA1 for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch, then just git checkout [sha]. And once you're at that commit, you can just git checkout -b [branchname] to recreate the branch from there.

You can do it in one step:

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

This is creating a new branch for that SHA1 with the name which you give.

Comment: I was not able to get sha by git reflog, that command was also failing

Comment: @user3616359 use this command to see the "git reflog" too see the reflog and follow the other command