# Github directly push to main

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

With the recent change of `master` to `main` in Github, it seems I need to first push to `master` and then merge with `main`. When I try push using the `--remote-upstream` to `main` I get an error:  `error: src refspec main does not match any`.

On iterm2 with OMZ, when I first run `git init` I see `master` in the path.

How do I push directly to main instead of master first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I recall correctly, in Git version 2.28.0, you can use the command `git init -b` in order to set up your default branch.

For example, to create a new repository with `main` branch as the default branch.

```
git init -b main
```

If you like to type longer names:

```
git init --initial-branch=main
```

You can even set it globally.

```
git config --global init.defaultBranch main
```

As an alternative, when creating a new repository, you can just do `git clone` to your system. The default branch will be adjusted accordingly.

---

About `git init -b` command, taken from Git's documentation:

> Use the specified name for the initial branch in the newly created repository. If not specified, fall back to the default name (currently master, but this is subject to change in the future; the name can be customized via the init.defaultBranch configuration variable).

Read more [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init).

---

Another alternative, just keep the default branch name as `master` in your remote repository.

Comment: Thanks! How do I change the branch to main in the existing repo and set it as the default remote?

Comment: If it is an existing remote, then it is pretty simple. Just do `git branch main`, `git checkout main`, `git push -u origin main`, then set that `main` branch as the default branch. You can find it in GitHub repository settings (in one of the top tabs). After you have successfully updated the default branch to `main`, feel free to delete the `master` branch.

Answer (score 2):

> With the recent change of master to main in Github, it seems I need to first push to master and then merge with main.

Actually no, [not with Git 2.31](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66297871/6309) (which will be released next Monday)
*
Any `git clone` of an empty GitHub repository will create a local repository with '`main`' as a default branch, even if `init.defaultBranch` was still set on `master`!

With protocol v2, GitHub will communicate to the client the name of the remote default branch (`main` for GitHub) to the local Git repository created by `git clone`.