# Push to github not working anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

How can I start a `repo` and `push` it to my `Github`?

I had it working fine before, but I kiled it after I tried to migrate over a db over. I erased all my remote repositories and cleared the local ones too.

I just want to start pushing my repo again. This is was I get now after I create a new repo on on github and followed the copy and paste instructions for terminal on the mac which worked fine until now.

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Hendrixer/Learning.git'
```

I've tried all the answers to the same problem with no luck. 
I'm new to developing in general, so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: How do you mean you 'erased' the remote repository?

Comment: What commands have you run?

Comment: What is the output of `git remote -v` and `git config --local --list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you committed yet? This error message sometimes indicates there is nothing to push. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git).

Comment: I did try to commit first with the same error. I deleted the local reop with the 'rf -rm .git' command and then 'git init' to form another. when I calling git remote -v I get this origin https://github.com/Hendrixer/treebook.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/Hendrixer/treebook.git (push)

Comment: I think its also supposed to have the scheme, i.e. https. Try `git remote add origin https://github.com/Hendrixer/treebook.git`

Comment: I got it. I had to "git add ." first before the commit.