# Github error: src refspec BRANCHNAME does not match any

Tags: git, shell, ubuntu, github, terminal

I forked a repo on GitHub. Created a new branch from website (named "anythingslider").
Then:

```
cd /home/multiformeingegno
git clone git@github.com:multiformeingegno/cdnjs.git
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': (done)
```

I do the changes I need to do on /home/multiformeingegno/cdnjs
Then I'd like to push my changes to anythingslider (not to master).

```
cd /home/multiformeingegno/cdnjs git add ajax/libs/anythingslider/*
git commit -m "Updated AnythingSlider to reflect original dir structure and added missing default.png"
git push origin anythingslider
Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': (done)
```

But I get a:

```
error: src refspec anythingslider does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:multiformeingegno/cdnjs.git'
```

What's the problem? I tried doing a pull to ensure I was up-to-date.. no luck.

*EDIT:* This is what I get if I do a git remote show origin:

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: git@github.com:multiformeingegno/cdnjs.git
  Push  URL: git@github.com:multiformeingegno/cdnjs.git
  HEAD branch (remote HEAD is ambiguous, may be one of the following):
    anythingslider
    master
  Remote branches:
    anythingslider tracked
    master         tracked
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (fast-forwardable)
```

Comment: Do you have a local branch called `anythingslider`? Can you do `git branch -a` and tell us the output of that command?

Comment: possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Github has actually been down intermittently in the past few days. https://status.github.com/messages

Whenever you have problems connecting on pushes or pulls from github, check https://status.github.com/ to see if they are having problems.

Comment: I don't think it was this because "git push origin master" worked. :(