# Cannot push to github, ssh: Could not resolve hostname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, ssh, push

I can't get pass this, have remade the repository multiple times, made ssh keys over

```
--------------
demo_app <username>$ git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/demo_app.git

fatal: remote origin already exists.

$ git push -u origin master
---
ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
---
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
---
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
---
and the repository exists.
----------
---------

Checked ssh keys

---

$ ssh -T git@github.com

Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

---
```

Still receiving the same message.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of adding a new remote, try to change the existing one with the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/demo_app.git
```

Edit: so, here are the commands to make it work without losing your code.

1. `rm -rf .git`
2. `git init .`
3. `git remote add origin git@github.com:<username>/demo_app.git`
4. `git commit --allow-empty -m 'First commit'`
5. `git push origin master`

Comment: tried that before, turns out i didn't do $ git add . before, I tried to create what i did before to get the error message but I got a diff error "error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<username>/demo_app0.git'

Answer (score 6):

### If you got here because you're on a proxy

**Try:**

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

If that works then you can add settings to your `~/.ssh/config` to always connect through `443`:

```
Host github.com
  Hostname ssh.github.com
  Port 443
```

More info here:
https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port/

Answer (score 0):

To answer the new error: "error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:/demo_app0.git'

I found this post really helpful: [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Essentially, try add your files and committing again.

`git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master`

This worked for me!