# error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I have tried to follow the solutions suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git) post but it didnt work and I am still getting: src refspec master does not match any.

Here is what I did: 
Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/162345) solution

```
// adding the file I created
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
```

When doing:

```
$ git push origin HEAD:master
b40ffdf..a0d1423  HEAD -> master // looks promising

// adding a remote
$ git remote add devstage -f <another git>
$ git merge devstage/master -s recursive -X ours
$ git push -u devstage master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
```

More information:

```
$ git branch 
* origin

$ git show-ref
refs/heads/origin
refs/remotes/devstage/master
refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/devstage
refs/remotes/origin/master
refs/remotes/origin/origin
```

So I am definitely missing refs/heads/master but dont know how to create it.

Thanks

Comment: How did you created your repo? What file you created?

Comment: @MichaelVer: git clone https://<UserName>@bitbucket.org/<My Repo>

Comment: recently Github changed  ```git push origin master``` to ```git push origin main```

Comment: It is duplicated questions Git: Message https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/git-message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From `git branch` it appears that somehow your local branch name is "origin".

You can rename the branch with `-mv` flag, like this:

`git branch -mv origin master`

After this `git branch` should show `master` :-)

Just to make sure the name is indeed the only thing that went astray, you can run `git log` and look at the last few commits - and compare them to the last few commits on bitbucket website.

Comment: To start working I did:
>git clone https://<User>@bitbucket.org/<RepoPath>

Which created the following .git/config
[core]
 repositoryformatversion = 0
 filemode = false
 bare = false
 logallrefupdates = true
 symlinks = false
 ignorecase = true
 hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[remote "origin"]
 url = https://<User>@bitbucket.org/<RepoPath>
 fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "origin"]
 remote = origin
 merge = refs/heads/origin

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: hmm, just doing `git clone repo_address` should be perfectly good. For some bizarre reason the local branch got named "origin" (evident from `branch [origin]` section of git/config). Why did it do it? I don't know. Did you try my suggestion of renaming the branch? If it doesn't work, you can also change your [branch] section of gitconfig manually to read as follows: 
`[branch 'master']
   remote = origin 
   merge = refs/heads/master`

Comment: Awesome!  I was running into this problem, too - it was because I had cloned a repo with a non-master branch checked out (which was what I wanted), but forgot to rename the branch `master` in the new repo.

Comment: I came here after I got an error while pushing to heroku, and found this answer useful after running
`git push heroku main`
Because at this time of posting github main branch is named `main` from `master`.
I hope it helps someone in future, probably me.

Comment: A brand new repo created in github was setup as main. After cloning we can see "main" instead of "master". So push in this case must be `git push -u origin main`

Answer (score 85):

This should help you

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: after  adding git add ., git push -u origin master works

Comment: and how is initiating a local git repo without adding it to remote going to help anyone???  You are missing the main step git remote add ....

Comment: Worked like a charm

Answer (score 43):

Try to do :

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Comment: It worked, but if you have to push to your own repo, what it does is, first reacted a pull request on my own repo and then I had to merge my own pull request.

Answer (score 38):

i have same problem, to solve it, follow these steps

```
 git init
 git add .
 git commit -m 'message'
 git push -u origin master
```

after this, if you still having that error, follow these steps again

```
 git add .
 git commit -m 'message'
 git push -u origin master
```

that worked for me and Hope it will help anyone

Comment: simple and elegant. Here take one from me soldier.

Comment: Nice, it helped me worked it out on my end

Answer (score 17):

By just adding an empty commit  will fix issue by using

```
$ git commit -m "empty commit" --allow-empty
$ git push
```

> above. make empty commit without edit then push

Answer (score 14):

#### Try following command:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

Git threw the below error when I tried simply `git push`. So clearly this is because Git matches the local and remote branch while pushing commits. This is the `push.default` behavior, you can find out more details [here.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:<Branch_Name>

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin <Branch_Name>

To choose either option permanently, see push.default in 'git help config'.
```

Answer (score 13):

I was having the SAME ERROR AGAIN AND AGAIN.

I added files in local repository and Trying the command

**"git push origin master"**

Showed Same Error

ALL I WAS MISSING I DID NOT COMMIT .

**" git commit -m 'message' "**

After Runnig this it worked

Comment: this works when you're on a new repo and have never committed.

Comment: Yup ! I faced this problem with my very first repository

Answer (score 7):

The clue is in the error

> error: src refspec master does not match any.

Github's recently changed its default branch to ***main***.
Take a look [here](https://github.com/github/renaming)

On your local setup you could rename your local branch as shown below

```
git branch -m master main
```

or you could push from your master to main

```
git push origin master:main
```

Answer (score 5):

Run the command `git show-ref`, the result `refs/heads/YOURBRANCHNAME`
If your branch is not there, then you need to switch the branch by

```
git checkout -b "YOURBRANCHNAME"
```

`git show-ref`, will now show your branch reference.

Now you can do the operations on your branch.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the error was caused because I was typing

`git push origin master`

while I was on the develop branch
try:

`git push origin branchname`

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 2):

**The error demo:**

```
007@WIN10-711082301 MINGW64 /d/1 (dev)
$ git add --all

007@WIN10-711082301 MINGW64 /d/1 (dev)
$ git status
On branch dev
Initial commit
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   index.html
    new file:   photo.jpg
    new file:   style.css

007@WIN10-711082301 MINGW64 /d/1 (dev)
$ git push origin dev
error: src refspec dev does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:yourRepo.git'
```

You maybe not to do **`$ git commit -m "discription"`**.

**Solution:**

```
007@WIN10-711082301 MINGW64 /d/1 (dev)
$ git commit -m "discription"
[dev (root-commit) 0950617] discription
 3 files changed, 148 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 index.html
 create mode 100644 photo.jpg
 create mode 100644 style.css

007@WIN10-711082301 MINGW64 /d/1 (dev)
$ git push origin dev
To git@github.com:Tom007Cheung/Rookie-s-Resume.git
 ! [rejected]        dev -> dev (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:yourRepo.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: Please copy the textual information from the picture directly to your answer. Then please explain how this is actually an answer to the question. I have the impression that it isn't one. It at least lacks an explanation of why it is not possible and how to actually solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is happend to me once I forgot to add files. So I got the same error. All you need to do is add your files.

1. Add your files => `git add .` or the name of the files you want to add. you supposed to init first your repo with `git init`.
2. Commit your changes =>  `git commit -m 'Initial Commit'`.
3. Now push your changes => `git push -u origin master`

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that if you are pushing the master branch then ensure that you're currently in the master branch if not checkout to the master branch and now push your commits. To list all current branches in your working directory use :

```
git branch
```

Your currently working branch should have an asterisk at the beginning for instance if am working on my a devstage branch it would appears as shown below :

```
*devstage
master
```

In this case, push the commits in the devstage branch first then perform a git pull request if you want to merge the two branches that is the master and the devstage.

Answer (score 2):

this error occurs when you clone a repo from one branch and you trying to push changes to another branch just try to make sure that you are in the same branch compared to the branch that you are trying to push if it isnot the same just clone your repo again from that specific branch by using `git clone -b <branchname> <remote-repo-url>` then retry to push changes

Answer (score 1):

Check that you call the git commands from the desired directory (where the files are placed).

Answer (score 1):

This error can typically occur when you have a typo in the branch name.

For example you're on the branch `adminstration` and you want to invoke:
`git push origin administration`.

Notice that you're on the branch without second `i` letter: `admin(i)stration`, that's why git prevents you from pushing to a different branch!

Answer (score 1):

Setup username and password in the git config

In terminal, type

```
vi .git/config
```

edit url with

```
url = https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git
```

type `:wq` to save

Answer (score 1):

Only because your local branch does not math the one in your remote repository.
git push origin HEAD:master 
Enable you to ignore the conflict and upload your commit anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**I had the same problem recently. but now resolved this issue.** Because, Now GitHub changed master to main. It works well for me. **Use `git push origin main` instead of `git push origin master`.** Hopefully, It will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the fix appears to be "git ." (stages all current files). Apparently this is required after a git init?
I followed it by "get reset" (unstages all files) and proceeded with the exact same commands to stage only a few files, which then pushed successfully.

```
   git . 
   git reset
```

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I discovered that github was trying to verify my account. **So you need these 2 commands:**

```
git config --global user.email <your github email>
git config --global user.name <your github username>
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, ran into same error, but believe it came about due to the following sequence of events:

- Remote Git repo was created with `master` branch.
- Local clone was then created.
- Remote Git repo was then modified to include a `dev` branch, which was defined as the default branch, in conjunction with permissions added to the `master` branch preventing changes without a pull request.
- Code updates occurred in the local clone, ready to be pushed to the remote repo.

Then, when attempting to push changes from the local to the remote, received error "src refspec master does not match any", or when attempting to push to `dev`, "src refspec dev does not match any".

Because changes were pending in the local clone, I did not want to blast it and refresh. 
 So, fixed the issue by renaming the local branch to `dev`...

`$ git branch -m dev`

...followed by the normal push of `git push origin dev`, which worked this time without throwing the aforementioned error.

Answer (score 0):

This error is also caused due to an **unmatched** **local branch name**.
Make sure that you are giving correct local branch name (**check spelling and case sensitivity**) 
I had the same error because my local branch name was "**validated**" and was trying to push the changes using `git push -f origin validate`, updated that to `git push -f origin validated` worked.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same error.
In my case below is the scenario.

I have master branch which set as origin.

Other side I have release branch "Release_branch".

I have to fork my feature branch(i.efeature/testBranch) from Release branch.

Below are the steps I did.

```
$ git checkout Release_branch
$ git pull
$ git checkout feature/testBranch
$ git commit -m "SOME_MESSAGE"
$ git push -u origin feature/testBranch
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error (`error: src refspec master does not match any`) with a new repository, when trying <strike>`git push origin master`</strike>, because GitHub changed the default name of the master branch to `main`.

So, `git push origin main` is working for me.

Answer (score -1):

For a new repository, the method works for me:

1. Remote the files related with git
   `rm -rf .git`
2. Do the commit again
   `git add . && git commit -m "your commit"`
3. Add the git URL and try to push again
   `git remote add origin <your git URL>`
4. And then try to push again

   `git push -u origin master -f`
5. Success!

Since it's a new repository, so it doesn't matter for me to remove the git and add it again.

Answer (score -1):

I had already committed the changes and added all the files, had the same origin as remote, still kept getting that error. My simple solution to this was just:

```
git push
```