# error: failed to push some refs | pushing local git repo

Tags: git

i'm trying to create a setup to push my local git repo to my web server, to later use post receive script to push changes from my website directly to the live website.

How i started:

1. Downloaded Git (https://git-scm.com/download/win)
2. Opend Git GUI and generated SSH key (without passphrase)
3. Copied that to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on my server from the user "myuser"
4. connected with terminal to my server and done the following:

```
$ cd ~
$ mkdir example.com.git
$ cd ~/example.com.git
$ git init --bare
$ exit
```

5. created local a folder on my desktop
6. opened git bash there
7. entered the following commands:

```
$ git config --global user.name "My Name"
$ git config --global user.email my@email.com
$ git init
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "First Commit"
```

8. Then i added the remote

```
git remote add scoutsofnature ssh://myuser@server.domain.tld/~/example.com.git
```

9. When i tried to git push with:

```
git push -u scoutsofnature master
```

it fails with following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to  'ssh://server.domain.tld:PORTNUMBER/~/example.com.git'
```

I'm likely new to git so would be nice if somebody can explain where i failed.

That are my references:

- https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/
- https://git-scm.com/

Best regards

Comment: I'm sure there were more error lines after `git push`. Can we see all of them?

Comment: `$ git push -u scoutsofnature master `
 `error: src refspec master does not match any `
 `error: failed to push some refs to  'ssh://server.domain.tld:PORTNUMBER/~/example.com.git' ` thats all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67545863/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Comment: same error when `$ git push -u scoutsofnature main`

Comment: `git status`? `git branch`? `git log`? Did `git commit` create any commit? I suspect it didn't because the directory is empty and `git add` didn't add anything.

Answer (score 0):

Just to test, try and replace ~ with the actual full path on your server.
For  instance:

```
git remote set-url scoutsofnature ssh://myuser@server.domain.tld/home/myuser/example.com.git
```

Then, as commented, check your `git status`/`git branch -avv` to make sure you are pushing the right branch.

Answer (score 0):

The real error here is in the *first* line (I edited your comment into the question); the second `error:` line is just a summary of the previous error(s).  The first line here is:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
```

which means quite simply that you don't *have* a `master` branch.

What we don't know if *why* you don't have a `master` branch, but many people have started using `main` as their initial and/or primary branch name.  Perhaps you have a `main` branch and should be using that name everywhere.

It's important to realize that *every Git clone has its own set of branch names*.  Your own repository may be using branches named `zorg` and `palpatine`<sup>1</sup> while some other related repository uses names like `leeloo` and `leia` *for the same purposes*.  It's pretty standard for us humans to want to, and therefore to actually do, use the *same names* in *different repositories*, but Git doesn't really care.  Git only uses the names to find commit hash IDs.  You are allowed to use different names on the two "sides" of a fetch or push operation.

Hence, you need to:

- find / decide on the names you want to use in *your* repository;
- find / decide on the names others want to use in *their* repositories; and
- use the appropriate kind of `git fetch` and/or `git push` operations to manage these.

For instance, if you want to use `gruber` to keep track of the main branch, while they're using `mcclane` for theirs, you might use:

```
git push diehard gruber:mcclane
```

to send your new main-branch commit to their main-branch.

---

<sup>1</sup>I was tempted to go back and swap out the *Star Wars* references for another Bruce Willis movie, but didn't get around to it.  Maybe Mr Glass from Unbreakable?