# Push to "fork" Git Error - src refspec master does not match any. failed to push some refs to 'https://

Tags: git, bash, github

I understand that similar topics have been posted on this site many times before.  I read them and tried all the suggestions.  Somehow, I still cannot successfully push the local code back to the "fork" in GitHub using Git Bash.

I "fork"ed a project, which is vlerdas-subscribe, in the GitHub by clicking the Fork button.

I cloned the fork into the current directory in my laptop using Git Bash (I gave my GitHub username while cloning)

I added some code to one of the project files.

I had problems when I used the command **git push origin master** while pushing the entire project to the "fork".  Some nice person on this site told me that the current version of the Git bash has a bug -- (for https) it does not prompt for username and password.  Therefore, I followed his advice and did the following; but I got "**src refspec master does not match any.  failed to push some refs to ...**"

```
vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git remote rm origin

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/vlerdas-subscribe.git

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/vlerdas-    subscribe.git'
```

I saw some suggestions to answer similar topics on this site;  therefore, I tried those suggestions but nothing seems to work.  I copied my command window below:

```
vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git branch

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git show-ref

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git commit -m "Initial commit."

On branch master
Initial commit

Untracked files:
    .bash_history
    .dbshell
    .eclipse/
    .editix/
    .m2/
    .mongorc.js
    .org.eclipse.epp.usagedata.recording.userId
    .ssh/
    .sysdb20/
    AppData/
    Contacts/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/
    Favorites/
    Links/
    Music/
    NTUSER.DAT
    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TM.blf
    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
    Oracle/
    Pictures/
    Saved Games/
    Searches/
    Tracing/
    Videos/
    Virtual Machines/
    client.cfg
    default-soapui-workspace.xml
    nodejs_test/
    ntuser.dat.LOG1
    ntuser.dat.LOG2
    ntuser.ini
    ntuser.pol
    soapUI-Tutorials/
    soapui-settings.xml
    vlerdas-subscribe/
    workspace/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$ git push origin master

error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/vlerdas-    subscribe.git'

vhaiswjenlim@VACOLTJENLIM ~ (master)
$
```

Comment: You need to change into the directory that you cloned the repository into.  You ran all those git commands in your home directory.  Maybe it's in that workspace directory?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

You've added the wrong origin.

Remove it and add the correct one:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/<your-username>/vlerdas-subscribe.git
```

where `<your-username>` should be replaced by your github username (eg. `John`).

Note that you also have to be in the root folder of the repository to do this.

Comment: No, OP is trying to push to OP's fork.