# Github fatal error - 'man git-pull'

Tags: macos, github

I'm pushing all these files into a repo, no problems after my last 4-5 pushes. But then I commit a bunch of new images that I've uploaded and then when I try to push them I get an error:

"fatal: No path specified. See 'man git-pull' for valid url syntax (128)"

I'm new to Github and I just want to get a better understanding of this error, what does it mean, what's going on? and what steps do I need to take to fix this myself

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619117/git-push-origin-master-returns-fatal-no-path-specified

Comment: What's the output of `git status`, and `git branch -a`?

Answer (score 2):

Check your git remote -v output.

As mentioned in "[`git push origin master` returns “`fatal: No path specified.`”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627029/6309)", the url might not be correct anymore.

If that is the case, this could fix it:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<yourLogin>/<yourRepo>
```

---

The other case is [when you don't add (and commit) anything before pushing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22799274/6309) (which shouldn't be your case).

Comment: how do I do that? Instead of the terminal, can I edit the files directly instead of comman line interaface?

Comment: @MarkToast simply type `cd /path/to/my/repo ; git remote -v output` i na terminal