# Lost some files in Git

Tags: git, github

I wanted to push a file to my GitHub account.

I did

```
git push origin master
```

and got an error

```
src refspec master does not match any.
```

I did

```
git push --force origin master
```

now all the other files in the repository are deleted

I want to reverse this step. How can I do that? Is it also possible to reverse changes through the web page interface in GitHub. Thanks.

Comment: You probably got your first error message because you never committed anything to your new repo yet, is that correct? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/456814).

Comment: We need more info about what previous steps and commands you used that led to your first error (did you `git init`, `git clone`).

Answer (score 0):

When something like that happens to me (very rarely) I can only think of `git reflog` which is a *commit history* of all your git commands.

So if you want to go back in time in a given git operation you can

```
$ git reflog
794e18b HEAD@{0}: commit (merge): Fixed conflicts
f9b382a HEAD@{1}: commit: Some minor errors on the file
1dc6496 HEAD@{2}: commit (amend): provisional tables for 
92f06d1 HEAD@{3}: commit (amend): provisional tables for 
a97a3a8 HEAD@{4}: commit: provisional tables for 
6ed9ebf HEAD@{5}: commit: @user changes.
8e79234 HEAD@{6}: commit: Changed the billboard and tables.sql
486acf6 HEAD@{7}: rebase -i (finish): returning to refs/heads/master
486acf6 HEAD@{8}: rebase -i (pick): Fixing some hal issues
e6d6e1a HEAD@{9}: rebase -i (pick): simple table definitions.
```

Now if I want to go back to let's say the `a97a3a8 HEAD@{4}: commit: provisional tables for` I just do

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{4}
```

Hope this saves your file :)

Comment: when i do git reflog it does not show the previous commits only the latest commit ..

Comment: I don't know why you don't have a reflog history, but this just means that you might want to stay a bit later today and re-write that file :(

Comment: He doesn't have a reflog history because he never even committed anything to his repo, probably. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868168/lost-some-files-in-git#comment34897635_22868168) to the question.