# src refspec ~ does not match any

Tags: git, push, clone, git-checkout, refspec

Hi I want to push something to specific remote branch

I make local areas by

```
git clone https://~~~.Something
cd https://~~~.Something
```

and I can access specific branch using

```
git checkout origin/[branch]
```

I want to commit something to my specific branch origin/[branch]
But when I am trying to push something using by

```
git push origin [branch]
```

I got this error

```
error: src refspec [branch] does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/kkammo/yonseitree.git'
```

I tried to solve this problem but I can't find any solution... so plz help me T.T

Comment: Did you not get a big warning message about `detached HEAD` when you did your `git checkout origin/[branch]`

Answer (score 44):

A replicated question here, [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Try `git show-ref` to see what refs do you have. Is there refs/heads/[branch]?

You can try `git push origin HEAD:[branch]` as more local-reference-independent solution.

It works for me.

Comment: "git show-ref" wasn't showing my branch, but after I performed "git push origin HEAD:[branch]", it showed up on the next "git show-ref" - thank you Luna!

Comment: Seems to do the trick, upvoted but could you add some explanation on why does it solve the issue?

Comment: should be marked as solution. Also would be nice to have explanation

Comment: I have the same error. The reason is that I did not commit anything to the local repo. After committing, everything's going well.

Answer (score 1):

Below is your now branch:

`* dev
      master
      remotes/origin/master`

The new branch `dev` is created from master and have been done some commits.

Use the command below to push this new branch:

`git push -u origin --tags  HEAD:dev`

After that, we check again:

`* dev
  master
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/master`

That's OK for me.