# How to remove git branch.master in linux terminal

Tags: git, ubuntu, config

When I try to install a project I get the following error .

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to ****
```

I looked this [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git), but could not find solution of my problem.

Link to my configuration [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN4P5.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem in your configuration.

Try to clone it again and it should work.

the configuration `master.remote` should be set to `origin` and not to `github`

this is why its not working for you.

Edit the `.git/config` and change it

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/omernaci/FilterDesign.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```