# Two SSH Keys - Cloud9 IDE and Windows Desktop - Push error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bitbucket, windows-7-x64, ssh-keys

I am new to Ruby-on-Rails and GIT.

I have been taking the tutorials from https://www.railstutorial.org (THANKS A LOT to Michael Hartl).

The tutorial recommended using Cloud9 IDE. As part of my first hello_app, I created a SSH key and added to bitbucket. The SSH key was generated from Cloud9 IDE.

Later, I wanted to try everything from my desktop (Windows 7). I was very successful in completing the exercise all the way to publishing through Heroku. During the process, I generated another SSH key from my desktop and added to bitbucket.

As I was trying the second exercise through Cloud9 IDE, the push command generated the following error:

error: src refspec all does not match any.

error: failed to push some refs to git@bitbucket.org:cprabhushankar/toy_app.git'

I believe this has something to do with the multiple SSH keys in bitbucket.

Please advise how to handle the two SSH keys - one from Cloud9 IDE and other from my desktop.

Thanks!

PC

Comment: Did you conduct a Google search of the error message you received - [error: src refspec all does not match any](https://www.google.com/search?q=error%3A+src+refspec+all+does+not+match+any.&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: I did the following command and it worked "git push origin master --force"