# GitHub: how to add Subfolders to a GitHub-Repository

Tags: xcode, git, file, github, directory

I´m very new in GitHub (since yesterday ;-)) and want to add files & folders

In my Xcode-Project i have this Folder-/File-Structure:

[image]

entries with the folder-icon as CodeDataTest, Classes, Model,... are Folders, the rest are files.
Now i want to add these structure to my new GitHub-Repository as shown.

I googled a lot but found no solution. :-(

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Evgeny Karkan the comments are gone??? Many Thanks! Send me a reply, so i can upvote u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Login GitHub, then click `Start a Project -> Create a new repository`, input your name `CoreDataTest`

2.Run `git init` in your local CoreDataTest directory.

3.Run the following command:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:xxxx/CoreDataTest.git
```

4.Finally, push local repository to remote

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: when using the git push - u origin master i get the errors error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:UlliH/UHCoreData.git'

Comment: see [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: "nothing added to commit but untracked files present"? I´m helpless... :-(

Comment: git remote -v tells 
origin git@github.com:UlliH/UHCoreData.git (fetch)
origin git@github.com:UlliH/UHCoreData.git (push)

Comment: Have your local directory already add to repository? `git add .`

Comment: no, i didn´t know, that i must do that :-( Its wasting a long time... I´ll be back afterwards...

Comment: Ok, i repeat it all and after _git push -u origin master_ i got the message **Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.
Everything up-to-date**. But i can´t see a resul. BTW Thanks a lot until here...

Comment: Do you run `git commit -m "xxx"`? `git status` see your current branch status

Answer (score 0):

I got it after wasting a lot of time...

In the accepted answer of **Em L** everything was correct, but me idiot added at github.com a new repository with adding a new README.md and this caused the error

```
 ERROR: Repository not found.
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
 Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

after a lot of tries, i added a new repository **without** a new README.md and everything was ok, but i don´t know the reason. :-( Till yesterday, when on a new try i finally noticed it...

So my solution in addition to Em L answer is

[image]

maybe it will help someone...