# How to use push production master in Git?

Tags: git

After running git push production master i got these error.

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/var/repo/site.git'

Comment: Shouldn't it be `git push origin master` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the proper way to fix it :

```
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link:

You will see how to init git in production server and client manchine, so you can use:

```
git push production master
```

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-hooks-to-automate-development-and-deployment-tasks