# git push to second git repo fail: error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git

I need work with a github repo on development mode.

For work with this proyect and after, upgrade form git (master) create my own git.

On my git server

```
cd /path/new/repo/l53bp
git init --bare
```

On local project

```
git remote add l53bp ssh:mysuser@mygitserver.com:myport/path/new/repo/l53bp
```

Write some changes.

```
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
```

Verify remotes

```
git remote -v
l53bp   ssh:mysuser@mygitserver.com:myport/path/new/repo/l53bp (fetch)
l53bp   ssh:mysuser@mygitserver.com:myport/path/new/repo/l53bp (push)
origin  https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate.git (push)
```

Change on master on local

```
git push -u l53bp master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh:mysuser@mygitserver.com:myport/path/new/repo/l53bp'
```

What it's wrong?

NOTE: Of course, ssh access to my repo, it's work.

Comment: On local, what is the output of: (1) `git --version` (2) `git config --get push.default`?

Comment: git push l53bp master

Comment: `git --version git version 2.7.4` `git config --get push.default simple`

Comment: git push l53bp master show same error

Comment: What is the output of `git status` and `git log -3`?

Comment: If you are working on branch `development` why do you push `master` (which most probably you don't have)?

Comment: OK, @Leon question confirms it: after you created the repository, you made one commit, but on branch `development`, so you have no `master` branch.

Comment: For `git status` and `git log -3` http://paste.tamainut.info/view/6685b0e3

Comment: Branch development it's branch of repor github what i like work. After, y like push all my work on my own master. After, when on development branch there're some changes pull and merged on my project.

Comment: BTW, there is a spelling error in your `user.name` git config entry

Comment: @Leon on .git/config there're any entry for user.name  (On any of my projects that use my own git repo show this)

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't show a `git checkout -b development` or `git checkout development` command, it's clear from the [result](http://paste.tamainut.info/view/6685b0e3) from [Leon's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994364/git-push-to-second-git-repo-fail-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any#comment67266939_39994364):

> ```
> git status
>
> On branch development
> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/development' by 1 commit.
>   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
> ```

that you have made your commits on branch `development` and not on branch `master`.

The result is that you have no branch `master` at all (there's nothing *wrong* with this, it's just a fairly unusual setup).  You can verify this with `git branch` or `git branch --list`, as [Leon notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994364/git-push-to-second-git-repo-fail-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any/39994795#comment67267479_39994795).

Since, however, you *do* in fact lack a `master` branch, this:

> ```
> git push -u l53bp master
> ```

will fail to push your `master` branch to remote `l53bp`.

You may *create* a `master` branch (with `git branch` or `git checkout -b` or similar), after which you can push it.  Or you can push `development` and never bother with a `master`.

Comment: Please add to your answer that he can verify the absence of the branch `master` in his local repo with `git branch --list`

Comment: `git branch --list * development`

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a commit after adding your changed files to stage.

Add to stage:

`git add .`

Then commit:

`git commit -m 'Initial commit'`

Have a look at [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git) . This is the same situation.

Comment: Of course, run this... Question it's about repos not about process on git. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git][1] . This is the same situation.

Comment: Thanks It's similar but not same. I work with develop branch of original github. That's it's problem. I'm try solution but get same result.