# Cannot push onto github

Tags: github

I want to pysh my project to a github repository called luna.git:

I followed the instructions 
    echo “# luna” >> README.md
    git init
    git add README.md
    git commit -m "first commit"
    git remote add origin https://github.com/raouiyounes/luna.git
    git push -u origin master

But I get this error

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: impossible de pousser des références vers ‘https://github.com/raouiyounes/luna.git’
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you just need to commit.

Try this:

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

Comment: error: src refspec master does not match any.
    error: impossible de pousser des références vers 'https://github.com/raouiyounes/luna.git'

Comment: The most probable reason for this error is that all the files are untracked and have not been added. `git add --all` in case you wish to add all the files Or you can selectively add files. Then `git commit -m "Initial comment"`, `git push origin master`. This will surely work.

Comment: Thanks it works.But there are some file which are not pushed. Is there any limit on the size of the project ?

Comment: Use `git add *` or `git add .` to add all files in a directory. If this helped you mark like answer please.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :

```
git push origin HEAD:branch-name
```