# Failing at "Adding an existing project to GitHub using the command line"

Tags: git, github

I'm perplexed at how little I know about git, so I'm trying to create a project on GitHub to get some practice.

I've created an **empty** repository on the website, following [this official guide](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)

Then, as suggested:

```
echo "# test" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
```

I also configured a mail and name for this repository and continued the guide:

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git remote add origin https://github.com/saatomic/test.git
git push -u origin master
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I try, I always get the following when I try to push the local data:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/saatomic/test.git'
```

I'm quite lost - as I've strictly followed the propsed guide by GitHub.

What am I doing wrong and how do I correctly push my local data?

*edit:*

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/saatomic/test.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/saatomic/test.git (push)
```

---

**Update:** I was able to do exactly the same on a different Linux VM, where everything succeeded as intended. This appears to be an issue of my local system. I can't grasp why (Updated Ubuntu 17.04), git version 2.11.0.

**Update #2:** I've retried the very same on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, git version 2.7.4, the same issue.

**Update 3:** Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git). I've tried all the suggestions there, I should have mentioned that.

I've tried to add, commit and change branches, as suggested. The pushes still fail with the same error message.

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/saatomic/test.git'
```

Also suggested (both report nothing at all):

```
$ git show-ref
$
$ git branch
$
```

Force pushes don't work either and I do have a pending commit:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   README.md
```

---

Solved: The issue was, that I had to configure the mail and username and **then make a new commit**.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git commit -m "post-conf commit"
```

Comment: Could you post your output from `git remote -v`?

Comment: @VíctorLópez I've edited the question and added the output

Comment: It seems all it's ok... If you run `git branch`, you're on master?

Comment: Then, you can check if your commit was commited, running `git log`. If not, follow the steps you told us (`git add .` and then `git commit -m 'message'`).

Comment: `git branch` returns nothing and `git log` states `fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet`.

Comment: Well, it's all we need. For some reason, your commit fails. `git status` will tell you if your file is tracked or not, and you could commit if it is. If not, use vim, nano or some editor to create a file in your git repository and the commit it. I think it will solve your problem :)

Comment: Very weird. `git status` states that I'm on branch master and that I have a commit "Initial commit" with the following changes to be commited: `new file:   README.md`

Comment: Try using `git push origin master:master`

Comment: @Claudio That results in the same error as shown in the question with `src refspec master does not match any.`.

Comment: @SaAtomic Can you provide the output of `show-ref`: `git show-ref`

Comment: @nash_ag I've just run the command and it reports nothing at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that I had to configure the mail and username and **then make a new commit**.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git commit -m "post-conf commit"
```