# Deploy python on heroku without github

Tags: python, git, heroku, github, tornado

**I want to deploy my project to Heroku without placing my project to github**? is this possible because I have to perform these steps and getting error. Here are the step i have performed

1. In my project i run this command `git init`
2. then i added some files `git add myProjectFiles`
3. I create a project on Heroku through `heroku create myprojectname`
4. Then i write this command to push my project on `git push heroku master` and i got this error:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> some refs to 'https:///git.heroku.com/tllwebsocekt.git'error: failed to push

5. Then i tried this `git push heroku`
   fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.
   To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

   git push --set-upstream heroku master
6. on this error i tried this `git push --set-upstream heroku master`
   but it also throw an error

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> some refs to 'https:///git.heroku.com/tllwebsocekt.git'error: failed to push

Comment: Don't confuse Git with GitHub. GitHub is a service for hosting Git repositories. Git is the version control tool. You do not need GitHub to use Git.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku will try build your app when you `git push heroku master`

In order for the app to be pushed successfully you'll need to `git commit` after `git add myProjectFiles` then specify the buildpack for you app:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
```

After specifying the buildpack add a `requirements.txt` either blank or:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
git add requirements.txt
git commit
```

Next you'll need to specify what command `heroku` should run when you've pushed the app with a `Procfile`:

example Procfile:

```
worker: python main.py
```

Then:

```
git add Procfile
git commit
```

Finally heroku will be able to build your app and it won't reject the push:

```
git push heroku master
```

---

**Alternatively if you have all the above in the `myProjectFiles` directory**

Initialise `git` from inside your app directory:

```
cd myProjectFiles
git init
git add *
git commit
heroku create myprojectname
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I will try it soon and inform you .

Comment: @MohammadFaizanKhan the suspense is killing me

Comment: I am really sorry i have get stuck in different problems. I am unable tried it yet. i will inform you. don't worry. if the problem get solve i will definitely accept it. dont worry

Comment: You be you babe, when it all works you'll be the happiest man alive, trust me.