# Error whenever I try to push files to my newly created repo on first commit

Tags: git, github

```
Ashan@DESKTOP-5GNFI1I MINGW64 ~/Desktop/SpyGlass (master)
$ git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/ashan1995/spyglass.git'
```

I used ***Gitbash*** from *Windows 10*.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Have you [followed these steps](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/), and, if so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: duplicate  issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
//Create a file.
touch README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "initial commit"
git push origin master
```