# Cannot push to feature branch on another remote repository

Tags: git, jenkins

I configured the following command in Jenkins to push change on gitA to gitB repository. However I got the following error:

```
 error: src refspec ... does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to ...

+ /usr/local/bin/git remote rename origin upstream
+ /usr/local/bin/git remote add origin ssh:<gitB repo>
+ /usr/local/bin/git fetch origin
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
+ /usr/local/bin/git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://<git repo>
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

However, I tried to git push origin origin/master and the Jenkins job execution is successful but no commit on the destination repo.

I have added ssh key. Please suggest what is missing here. I also tried to see the source branch using git branch and it's correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to push an empty repository. Add the initial commit.

- git add .
- git commit -m "initial commit"
- git push origin master
- git push upstream master