# Master is not showing when trying to push with SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I created a local repo with an existing project, also created a remote repo. But, when I try to push there are no branches in the box:

[image]

If I try to push with the terminal I get an error:

`git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.`

How come there is no master?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: All that is done by SourceTree. Just click 'Create a local repository' and then check 'Also create remote repository'. I guess is a bug.