# Want to understand the reason for error: src refspec master does not match any. error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xyz.git''

Tags: git, github, version-control

Trying to add version control for webpage, have used git before for various projects, never encountered this error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/aman-tugnawat/MangoDevelopersWebpage.git'
```

Looked a these answer for solution yet no progress, at these links.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7543112/4382835

[src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

The possible reason I am thinking:
[image]

Still trying to understand though what Github request's to skip the step of initializing the README.md.

Followed exactly in this sequecne:

```
git init
echo "# MangoDevelopersWebpage" >> README.md
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/aman-tugnawat/MangoDevelopersWebpage.git
git push origin master
```

Want an understanding of whats happening rather than the code.

Comment: What's the name of your local branch, `master`?

Comment: yeah, it's `master`, I solved the problem, but still need explaination.

Comment: what i did was remove the README.md, which I added after the git init.

Comment: Github suggests not to add README.me if you already have some existing files in your repo, i think the reason lies there, can anyone explain me the reason.

Comment: @MincongHuang could you please tell if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think README.md is the problem here. Without README.md in the initialization, GitHub creates an empty repository for you—but it doesn't block your from pushing a new branch. I think you might have done a `git push origin master` before commit as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

had you checked if you have initialize correctly globals like user.email, user.name ?
That's worked fine for me.

first you can check :

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$ git config --list
```

**if anything is wrong, so do as follows** :

step 1:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$ git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in C:yourPath/your-repo
```

step 2:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$ git add .
```

step 3:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$ git commit -m "second commit"
```

step 4:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

step 5:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$  git config --global user.email you@example.com
```

step 6:

```
you@yourPC MINGW64 ~/your-file(master)
$  git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Understood

> Why Github suggests not to make README.md when creating push a already existing local repo to a new remote repo at GitHub?

As that would require a `git pull` to merge of the local and remote Repo, which might be hard for beginners to understand.

Solved the problem by removing by force removal of README.md

```
git rm README.md -f
```

then

```
git commit origin master
```

Read more about: `git merge` here
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge

Comment: You can mark the answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

i had same error

when you first time connect to github or sth like that

you need to config

i solve it by git GUI

gitGUI want me to connect and problem resolved

1. go to your project folder
   [image: project forlder git GUI]
2. open Git GUI here
3. from main bar in app choose remote 
   [image: add remote by git gui]
4. copy url from your new repository in github into this form
   [image: copy git https url paste it in GIT GUI]
5. then stage changes
6. then commit them
7. then push
8. then it open prompt for user pass