# Error while pushing code to github public drive

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I am new to github and trying to create my first repository. After executing the below command:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

I am getting following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rs/python-gtts.git
```

Few things I did,

Created a folder in my local: `/Users/TrainingLearning/github/Python`

After that executed following command:

```
echo "# python-gtts" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
```

Then added my code (Python file - `TextToSpeech.py`) to the same folder where I earlier created README.md file: `/Users/TrainingLearning/github/Python`

And tried doing:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first commit"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/rs/python-gtts.git
```

But when I execute following command:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

I started getting following error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rs/python-gtts.git'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: what is the output of `git branch | grep master`?

Comment: Nothing it just moves to the next line

Comment: Another thing when I execute following command                                                   $ git commit -m "first commit"

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"                                                                                              So I run git config --global xxxx.xxxxxx@gmail.com but still I am not able to push my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, my git was not properly configured, so I had to run following commands:

$ git config --global user.email "xxxx.xxxx@xxxxx.com"
$ git config --global user.name "xxxx"

After this I was successfully able to push my code into git by running following commands:

$ git commit -m "Initial Commit"
$ git push -u origin master