# Failed to push some refs in Git

Tags: python, github, heroku

I am trying to upload my bot to Heroku and i ended up getting this error. I don't know what to do now. I tried to do what someone else on Stack Overflow said to do on someone else's problem and it didn't help me.

```
> git push heroku master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/flankebot.git'
```

I have tried to do the `git pull --rebase` then tried to repush it and it done nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [src refspec master does not match any when pushing commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: I've restored the edit from @c.berger, please do not roll it back again. We prefer text over images of text here, since text works better with clipboards, screen-readers and search engines. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First check if you are on a branch with `git branch` and `git status`.

If your branch is *not* master, then type:

```
git push heroku myBranch:master
```

(replacing myBranch with your current branch name)

Comment: This still didnt help me. I am so confused

Comment: What does your git status return?

Comment: Bunch or red lines

Comment: @ZemoGraphics I meant, what is the text (output) returned by `git status`?