# Getting problem to upload project from local machine to Azure DevOps

Tags: wordpress, azure-devops

I want to upload my local machine wordpress website on Azure DevOps so i follow this steps but getting some errors. Please let me know the solution of this issues

[command line steps screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NrEu.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Read the logs and focus on the first error you see.

**You didn't commit any files.**

`commit -m 'message'` only commits **staged** files. You didn't stage any files first.

You can either do `git add .` prior to committing, or you can do `git commit -am 'message'` to stage the contents for commit.