# How do I configure GitLab to mirror my repositories to Gemfury?

Tags: git, gitlab, mirroring, gem-fury

I use GitLab.com for my PHP repository management. However, I package my repositories for use with Composer. Right now, I'm using Satisfy to generate my packages, but this solution is not well developed, and has problems. I have decided to move to a commercial service, and GemFury seemed to be the best option.

I want to have GitLab mirror my repositories to GemFury, so that GemFury can generate a Composer-style repository automatically for me.

I attempted to use the Repository Mirroring settings in GitLab, but continually receive errors, of the form "fatal: remote error: Git repository not found". I understand what that means, but it is to be expected that the remote repository does not exist yet.

I feel that I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Welcome! Maybe you should use a Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline in order to manage the builds, instead of the mirror feature, since "is to be expected that the remote repository does not exist yet".

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've managed to set up a Gitlab CI, but I'm still seeing errors when it goes through the test phase...

$ git remote add fury https://myuser:my-push-token@git.fury.io/myuser/my-repository-name.git
$ git push --tags fury master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://myuser:my-push-token@git.fury.io/myuser/my-repository-name.git'

If I connect to my development server, and run the same "git remote add" and "git push --tags fury master", all works as expected. I just can't get it working in CI.

Any thoughts?

Comment: did you already check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: Thanks -- I somehow missed that when searching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Iron Bishop, I was directed here: [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

The solution was to change my git push to explicitly push the master branch of HEAD. My .gitlab-ci.yml now looks like this...

```
fury:
  script:
    - git remote add fury https://centralstationmarketing:14SAHV-r9GN71uqsu3ayYLNSf3onhLbW4@git.fury.io/centralstationmarketing/acela.git
    - git push --tags fury HEAD:master
```