# GITLAB-CI: Deploy on site using GIT

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

I'm here to try to understand what's wrong with my CICD.

The context:

- source code is hosted into à private GITLAB projet
- web app (laravel/php) is hosted by GANDI (simplehosting)
- on simplehosting offer, it is possible to [deploy application using GIT](https://docs.gandi.net/en/simple_hosting/connection/git.html#connect-git)

My target is to manage a cicd pipeline (using gitlab-ci) in order to check code quality, run unit tests and deploy automatically on a test/stage environnement. And later deploy on production on manual action.

My is issue is on deploy stage: How to push (deploy) my gitlab repo into the hosting git?

My initial concern was that there is nothing to push (view from my runner/image).
I had and `src refspec` error.

```
$ git push gandi master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git+ssh://xxx@git.sd6.gpaas.net/test.domain.tl.git'
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I tried a solution proposed in [4181861](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git) using `HEAD:` option in my `git push`.
And the `Job succeeded`.
But ... **there is NO UPDATE** on the hosting server!!

I understand that there is no update to push on the runner point of view.

```
$ git status
HEAD detached at ff1ce8c
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

So what to do?
I'm looking for new avenues to explore.

---

My gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: php:latest

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client git -y )'
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'
  - ssh-add <(echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")

stages:
  - deploy

job_deploy_staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy the app into (gandi) staging environnement"
    - git config --global user.email "$GIT_EMAIL" && git config --global user.name "$GIT_NAME"
    - git remote add gandi git+ssh://$GANDI_USER@$GANDI_GITSERVER/$GANDI_GITREPO_TEST
    - git status
    - git show
    - git push gandi HEAD:master
  environment:
    name: staging
    url : http://test.domain.tl
  only:
    - master


job_deploy_prod:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy the app into (gandi) production environnement"
    - git config --global user.email "$GIT_EMAIL" && git config --global user.name "$GIT_NAME"
    - git remote add gandi git+ssh://$GANDI_USER@$GANDI_GITSERVER/$GANDI_GITREPO_PROD
    - git push gandi master
  environment:
    name: production
    url : http://www.domain.tl
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

Comment: You have to checkout full git repo. Do `GIT_STRATEGY: clone`, otherwise the tree is only fetch. `'[[ -f ... '` - no need to quote, you can remove the `'`.