# Sync two git repositories

Tags: git

I have a git repository which I am pushing changes to remote X.
Now, I created another git remote (different repository), and I want to push my changes to it as well.
Ideally, I would like to keep to two sync.  By making changes in one and pushing to the other.

I added the new remote to my git.
I made a commit and pushed all changes to one repository (origin)
However when I try to push the changes:

```
git push my-new-remote-origin my_current_branch:master
```

I get this error :

```
error: src refspec my_current_branch does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to <NEW_GIT_REPO_ADDRESS>
```

Is my solution correct? Why is it failing (should I specify the commit to push?)

Comment: Or more likley [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: Looked at both it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Ok well your going to need to provide us with a [mcve] then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `--mirror`. This will sync your new reposoitory.

> Instead of naming each ref to push, specifies that all refs under
> refs/ (which includes but is not limited to refs/heads/,
> refs/remotes/, and refs/tags/) be mirrored to the remote repository.
> Newly created local refs will be pushed to the remote end, locally
> updated refs will be force updated on the remote end, and deleted refs
> will be removed from the remote end. This is the default if the
> configuration option remote..mirror is set.

Use the following command:

```
git push --mirror my-new-remote-origin
```

Documentation found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---mirror).

Comment: Is there a way to limit it to sync only my current branch?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to limit it. But what if I will delete from local all the old refs and trigger the command? Will it work

Comment: It won't trigger the command, you'll still need to use `git push --mirror`

Comment: Yes I was referring to this steps as something that needs to be triggered before running the --mirror command

Comment: Yes, if you use `git push --mirror origin` it will mirror your local repo with the origin you're pushing to.