# How to push to coworker's branch in Azure Repos

Tags: azure-repos

We use Azure Repos as source control in our project. A developer has created a branch named "testBranch" and gave access to the team so everyone can push to that branch.
What are the correct git commands for team members to push their changes to "testBranch"?

Answer (score 0):

Before a push make sure every developer pulls changes pushed by others first.
To do so:

```
git pull origin testBranch
```

You may get to see merged changes, or conflicts. Depending on your choice of editor for conflict resolution, you should be able to resolve conflicts locally.

Now you can add and commit locally all the files you need to push by :

```
git add filename.py
git commit -m "changes made for so and so module"
```

now you can happily push the changes

```
git push origin testBranch
```

You can also set upstream branch when you know you need to make multiple pushes or pulls.

```
git branch --set-upstream-to testBranch
```

This will trim down your pull and push commands to not having to mention "origin testBranch"

Comment: We get this when pushing to testBranch **$ git push origin testBranch
error: src refspec testBranch does not match any.**

Comment: This may help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: Unfortunately it is not. We have master branch and it works one. What we are looking at is how to work on a coworker branch which already has some commits.

Answer (score 0):

We were missing HEAD in the command. This did the trick:

```
git push origin HEAD:testBranch
```