# Cannot git push

Tags: git, github, git-push

I'm running into an issue when I git push (Via CLI or Github Desktop) on Windows.

```
C:\code\MHPanel>git push origin develop
error: src refspec develop does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Modern-Hosting/Panel.git'
```

I've tried deleting tags to no avail.

I've also tried remaking the local repo I have by doing

```
mkdir MHPanel
cd MHPanel
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/Modern-Hosting/Panel.git
```

Then making a change (New file) and committing then pushing results in the same original error.
Previously I was able to push to a different branch just fine until I removed the branch and switched back to this main develop branch.
Others are able to push to the branch successfully. Branch is also private too.

Comment: If you change it to `git push -u origin develop` do things go any better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Comment: `git push -u origin develop` Doesn't fix the error.
I'm not making use of master nor main.

Comment: @Modern_Mo Can you add the output of `git branch && git log -n1`?

Comment: ```C:\code\MHPanel>git branch && git log -n1
* master
commit 1e722b9f1881cf2d2113ce6cc2aba4591dc3e0e0 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Modern Mo <modernmogamer@gmail.com>
Date:   Mon Nov 23 11:20:40 2020 -0500

    add test file for fixing push```

Answer (score 1):

After further looking through the branch, My colleague made a commit named `refs/heads/develop` Although you'd believe `git tag -d refs/heads/develop` to work, it didn't as the tag was already on the remote repository (pushed to github).

The solution was to go onto the github repo on github's website (Not CLI or Desktop) and deleting the tag & release with the name, then performing the local git tag deletion with `git tag -d refs/heads/develop` to work

Thank you for those who helped me find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

This

```
error: src refspec develop does not match any
```

means that there is no local branch named `develop` which can be pushed to origin. Try creating the `develop` branch locally before pushing:

```
mkdir MHPanel
cd MHPanel
git init
git remote add origin https://github.com/Modern-Hosting/Panel.git
git touch newfile # or make changes
git commit -m 'Initial Commit'
git checkout -b develop # creating a local branch called "develop"
git push -u origin develop
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified, I got `src refspec develop does not match any` after deleting the ref file. Though I get `error: dst refspec refs/heads/develop matches more than one` when ran on fresh clone. I've also just reinstalled git & Github Desktop to no avail. 
Github Desktop works on other branches for pushing.

Comment: deleting the ref file? Not sure what that means.  What about this answers suggestion to create a branch (the `git checkout -b develop` part ?

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following command:

```
git push --set-upstream origin develop
```

Comment: I get this error: `Updates were rejected because the tag already exists in the remote.`