# git push command conflicts with master and main

Tags: git

When I run `git push -u origin main` on the terminal, it says `error: src refspec main does not match any.`

But when I run `git push -u origin master`, it works correctly and it creates another `master` branch in the repo along with the default `main` branch and the total branches will be 2.

At this point, I can't do a PR to merge the `master` to the `main` and the error message is `there's no diff between master and main branches.`

Can anyone explain this condition and give me a working solution? Your support will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you do not have a branch called "main" in your local repository.

Comment: so what's the solution?

Comment: I don't know – you can only push those branches that exist. Maybe create the branch first?

Comment: I didn't get that. I don't have a local branch called 'main' I think.

Comment: Yes, that's why you can't push it. It's not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I just need to push my code to the GitHub repo. This's actually the initial commit.

Comment: And did you not achieve that by using `git push -u origin master`?

Comment: `git push -u origin master` command works and it will create 2 branches eventually with the main branch. I want to have only one branch either main or master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't so hard to perform this action actually. What I found was when we initialize a  new GitHub project, it automatically creates the `main` breach as the default branch.

Then we can push our existing project to GitHub using the below commands.

```
git init
git add <file-name>
git commit -m "msg"
git remote add origin <remote-URL>
```

Next, before moving to the `git push` command, let's run `git branch` command to check available branches.
`git branch` shows the local branches while `git branch -r` shows the remote branches.

Here's my output.

```
randiltennakoon@Randils-MacBook-Pro test_bmi_app % git branch
* master
randiltennakoon@Randils-MacBook-Pro test_bmi_app % git branch -r
```

You can see there's no output for `git branch -r` command yet. But it shows the `master` as the local branch.

Then we need to run the below command to move `master` to `main`

```
git branch -m master main
```

Then you can run the `git push` command along with the `-f` flag as below.

```
git push -u -f origin main
```

Then it will push your changes to the remote `main` branch and you can verify it by going to your repo in GitHub.

Then you can issue the below commands to verify and this works pretty well.

```
git branch
git branch -r
```

OR

```
git branch -a
```

Comment: Using `git push -u -f origin main` is what I suggested as solution #3, **after** determining that you want to **throw away** the commit(s) in the GitHub repository. If you do this without looking, you're throwing away stuff you haven't looked at: is that a good idea?

Comment: yeah, that worked. Thanks for the support. Your info helped me to get the direction

Comment: Note that when you create a GitHub repo, you can choose to create it with *no commits* (and no initial branch), which removes the need for the `--force` option. That might be the route you want for future repositories. Alternatively, after creating a GitHub repo, instead of using `git init` and `git remote add` locally, use `git clone` to *copy* the GitHub repo to a new repo on your local system, which will get the initial commit they made so as to have an initial branch. (GitHub is trying to do a service by creating this branch for you—whether it's a service or disservice is up to you!)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you'd like a simple formula, *do X then Y and it will all work*.  Unfortunately we can't give you this without more information from you.  At the end, I'll suggest a few possibilities, but *you must inspect both your commits, and the commits found in the repository over on GitHub.*

## What's going wrong

The ultimate problem here is that Git is not *about* **branches**.  Git is all about *commits*.  Branch names do matter, because branch names help us—and Git—*find* the commits.  But it's really the *commits* that matter.  The branch names only matter for finding the commits; after that, the names stop being important—which is why you're free to *change* them at any time.

The *commits themselves* are numbered.  Those commit numbers, or *hash IDs*, are the way Git *really* finds the commits.  If you have the number, that's all you really need: give that to Git and Git will find the commit, if you have it.  The problem with the numbers is that they're incomprehensible and impossible for humans to deal with.  For instance, [`2283e0e9af55689215afa39c03beb2315ce18e83`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2283e0e9af55689215afa39c03beb2315ce18e83) is the hash ID for a commit in the Git repository for Git.  Nobody wants to remember this!  So we use a *name* like `master` or `main` to remember it for us.

When you use `git push`, you are telling *your* Git to call up some other Git, in this case over at GitHub (`origin` = `https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git`, per [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66302737/git-push-command-conflicts-with-master-and-main#comment117219581_66303342)).  Your Git and their Git have a conversation.  Your Git lists out your commit hash IDs, and theirs lists out theirs (with a lot of fancy algorithmic work to minimize this communication) so that your two Gits can agree which commits you have, that they don't, that your Git wants to send *to* them.

Then, your Git sends these commits to them.  They put them in a temporary quarantine area while they check out the rest of what you want to do.  Your Git now asks their Git to set some of *their* branch names, to remember these new commits.

Your Git can ask their Git to set their `master`.  If you tell your Git to do that, and they don't *have* a `master`, they'll generally say "OK!" and do it.  After that, they will have your commits, under their name `master`.  But to do that you'd have to run a Git command you haven't run (yet).

Your Git can ask their Git to set their `main`.  If you tell your Git to do that, and they *do* have a `main`, they'll take a look at the commits you just sent.  Do those commits *add on* to their `main`?  Or do those new commits just *wipe out* their existing commits, as found from their name `main`?

This is where your *later* push, in that comment, is failing:

> ```
> $ git push -u origin main
> To https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git
>  ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git'
> hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
> ```

Here, you changed your name `master` to your name `main`, to match *their* name `main`.  That's fine on its own—you can use any names you like, and most people find it helpful to use the *same* names in *their* Git as someone else (e.g., GitHub) is using.  Then you asked your Git to call up their Git, send them your `main`-branch commits, and ask them to set their `main` to remember *your last commit*.

Here, we need to take a side trip.  I'll try to keep it brief but there is a lot to know here!

#### What's in a commit

We've already mentioned that Git is all about commits, and that they are numbered.  If you run `git log`, your Git will show you your commits—all of them, in your case, because you have only one branch—along with their hash IDs (commit numbers), in reverse order.

These numbers will *look* random.  They're actually not random at all: they are computed with a cryptographic hash from the entire contents of the commit.  This is how Git makes sure that every commit gets a *unique* number.  But it also means that no part of any existing commit can ever be changed.  Whatever numbers your existing commits have, those *are* their numbers.  Every Git everywhere—yours, the one over on GitHub, mine, Fred's, *every* Git—agrees that *those are the right numbers for those commits*.  No other commits get those numbers, ever, anywhere.  This is why the numbers are so big and ugly.

Now, every commit—regardless of its number—consists of two parts:

- One part of a commit is a *full snapshot of every file* that Git knew about, as of the time you, or whoever, made the commit.  That is, after your `git add .` (or whatever) and `git commit`, Git made a snapshot of *all* of the files it knew about at that time: that's any you added, plus any it already knew about.  Git actually uses the versions of those files that are in Git's *index* [a.k.a.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/aka) *staging area* at this time, rather than the versions you can see and work with, but we'll skip over this detail.
- The other part of a commit is what Git calls its *metadata*, or information about the commit itself.  Here, Git stores your name, as the author of your commit, and your email address.  Git adds a date-and-time-stamp.  Git includes your *log message* where you explain *why* you made this commit (not what's in it, which we can see from the snapshot part of the commit, but rather *why* you did whatever you did, which we *can't* see from the snapshot).  And, crucially for Git itself, Git adds the hash ID of the *previous* commit.

These hash IDs wind up forming a backwards-looking chain.  Let's draw one, using single uppercase letters to stand in for the mind-bending hash IDs:

```
A <-B <-C
```

This is a simple chain of three commits, as you'd find in a nearly-new Git repository.  Commit `A` is the very first commit.  It doesn't have any earlier commit—it can't; it's the *first* commit—so it doesn't point backwards at all.  Commit `B`, however, is the *second* commit, so it points backwards to `A`, the first commit.  Commit `C`, currently the *last* commit, points backwards to `B`.

In reality, commit `C` literally contains the actual commit number—hash ID—of earlier commit `B`, as part of `C`'s metadata.  Similarly, `B` contains the hash ID of earlier commit `A`.

In order to find *all three* commits, Git just needs the hash ID of the *last* of these three commits.  We have Git stick this hash ID into a name, like `master`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
```

If we change the name from `master` to `main`, none of the *commits* change:

```
A--B--C   <-- main
```

So this is trivial: we can change our branch names around all we like.  A `git checkout` of whichever branch name we pick will actually *get* commit `C`—whatever its real hash ID is—because the one name we have, has the hash ID of commit `C` in it.

If we make a *new* commit, our new commit—which we'll call `D`, although in reality it gets some big ugly hash ID—will contain, as its backwards link, the hash ID of commit `C`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main
```

This is how a branch grows.  The backwards connection from `D` to `C` says that the *parent* of commit `D` is commit `C`.  The parent of `C` is `B`, and so on, except that once we hit `A`, there's no parent at all, and it all stops.

#### GitHub has a Git repository too

Meanwhile, over on GitHub, as found by the URL `https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git`, there's *another Git repository*.  This other Git repository has some commits.  Those commits have some hash IDs.

If those commits were the *same commits* that you have—if they had the same `A-B-C` for instance—you'd be in good shape.  You'd have your Git call up their Git.  Your Git would list out hash ID `D`.  They'd say: *Hey, I don't have `D`, why don't you give me that one?*  Your Git would add `D` to the list of commits to send over.  Then your Git would say *the parent of `D` is `C`*.  They would check and see that they *do* have `C`.  This means they also have `A` and `B` and so the only commit your Git has to send is `D`.

Then, your Git would send just `D`, and ask them to set *their* `main` to remember `D` instead of `C`.  That would be fine, because `D` itself remembers `C`.  You're just *adding on to their commits*.

Alas, this is not what's happening.  Instead, they have, e.g.:

```
G--H   <-- main
```

in *their* repository.  So if you send them your entire series of commits, they'll end up with:

```
A--B--C--D

G--H   <-- main
```

Then your Git ask them to set their `main` to point to `D`.  This will *lose their commits*.  The name `main` can only point to *one* last commit, such as `H` or `D`.  Switching to `D` *does not* add on to their commits.  So they refuse.

## How you fix it

What you need to do is:

1. Obtain *their* commits.
2. Decide *how to combine your commits and their commits*.

Step 2 is a *big decision*.  It's the one we can't make for you.

Step 1 is easy: just run `git fetch`.  When it's done, you will have an `origin/main`.  This name is not a *branch* name, but it's almost as good in most ways, and better in one specific way: It's how your Git *remembers* **their** Git's branch name.  Each `git fetch` you run will get any new commits from them, then update your memory of their Git's `main` branch name (and any other branches).<sup>1</sup>

In any case, this `origin/main` lets you see their commits—now in *your* repository too, found by the same hash IDs that *their* Git is using, because every Git agrees that *those* commits get *those* IDs.  You now have their commits *and* your commits.  These don't hook up with each other, because you made your commits *completely independent* of theirs, by making yours without starting with theirs.

Run:

```
git log origin/main
```

to see all of *their* commits.  What commits do they have?  What's *in* those commits?  Are they important?  Should you keep those commits?  If so, *how* do you want to *combine* **your** commits with theirs?

---

<sup>1</sup>The exact details here depend on what *kind* of `git fetch` you run.  The `git pull` command, for instance, runs a limited `git fetch` that doesn't pick up everything.

---

#### Combining method #1: `git merge`

The simplest method of combining two strings of commits is to use `git merge`.  This is still true in your case, but there's a hitch.

Normally, with `git merge`, we start with something like this:

```
          I--J   <-- ours
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- theirs
```

That is, we have a branch—we're calling it `ours` in this drawing—that *ends at commit `J`*, and they have a branch that ends at commit `L`.  We have Git combine these two branches.  Git does so by finding commit `H`, which Git calls the *merge base*.  You can see from this drawing that commit `H` is the *best shared commit*.  We start at the two branch ends—commits `J` and `L`—and begin working backwards, the way Git always does.  From `J`, we go back to `I`, then to `H`, and `G`, and so on.  From `L`, we go back to `K`, and then `H` and `G` and so on.

These two traversals *meet up* at commit `H`.  They keep meeting up from there on back, so commit `H` is automatically the *best* (i.e., last) commit at which the two branches met.  The merge operation then figures out what *we've* changed since commit `H`, and what *they* changed, and combines these changes.

I don't know precisely what's in your Git and their Git, but I do know, from the way you went about making these two Git repositories, that what you have and what they have *never meet up*.  You have something like:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main

G--H   <-- origin/main
```

If we start at each end and work backwards, we never meet up.

Since Git version 2.9, `git merge` won't merge these by default.  It just complains that the histories are unrelated, and stops.  You can tell Git to go ahead and merge anyway, using `--allow-unrelated-histories`.

*Whether this works at all* depends on what's in the *snapshots* in `D` and `H` (or whatever last commits you have).  If you get merge conflicts, you must resolve the merge conflicts yourself.  Once that's all done—all conflicts are resolved, or there were no conflicts—Git can make a new *merge commit*, which I'll call `M` for `Merge`:

```
A--B--C--D
          \
           M   <-- main
          /
G--------H   <-- origin/main
```

What's special about commit `M` is that instead of just one parent, such as `D` or `H`, it has *both* of these as its *two* parents.  So it combines the two separate chains of commits.

Assuming you *want* to make `M`, and *did* make `M`, you can now run:

```
git push -u origin main
```

You'll send, to the other Git, commits `A-B-C-D-M`.  Commit `M` links back to commit `H`, which is where *their* `main` is right now.  So if they obey your Git's polite request to set their `main` to point to `M`, they'll keep their `G-H` commits too.  They'll decree that this is fine.

What's in commit `M` as a *snapshot* is the result of combining the two commits.  If you have to do the combining by hand, because of merge conflicts, *you* pick what goes into commit `M`, as a snapshot.  If Git is able to do the combining on its own, Git will make commit `M` on its own, and it will have everything you had in `D`, and everything they had in `H`.

#### Combining method #2: `git rebase`

The rebase command is quite complicated and I won't explain it properly here.  See other StackOverflow answers for more.  Instead, I'll just note that it works by *copying* commits, as if by running `git cherry-pick`.

Let's assume that you do indeed have this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main

G--H   <-- origin/main
```

If you run `git rebase origin/main`, your Git will save the four hash IDs for commits `A-B-C-D`, in a temporary file.  Your Git will then use `git cherry-pick` or equivalent to *copy* each commit, in the `A-B-C-D` order (forwards! Git has to list them out backwards, then reverse the backwards list to do this), to come after commit `H`.  If we call the *copy* of `A`, `A'`, and the copy of `B` `B'`, and so on, we can draw the result like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main

G--H   <-- origin/main
    \
     A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- ???
```

The question marks show that there's a problem here: how will your Git *find* the copy `D'`?  The answer is: it yanks the *name* `main` off the old series of commits, and pastes it onto the end of the new series.  The result is:

```
A--B--C--D   ???

G--H   <-- origin/main
    \
     A'-B'-C'-D'   <-- main
```

It's now very difficult to *find* the old commits.  If you saved their hash IDs somewhere (on paper, on a whiteboard, in a file, whatever), you can use those.  There are other tricks Git has to help you find these commits for a while—for at least another 30 days, by default—but for most purposes commits `A-B-C-D` *seem* to be **gone**.  As a result, when you use `git log` to look at your commits, you'll now have only *six* commits, not ten: `git log` will show you commit `D'`, then `C'`, and so on.  When it gets to `A'`, well, commit `A'` *does* have a parent: it links back to commit `H`.  So after `A'`, `git log` shows `H`, and then `G`, and *then* stops because the commits have run out.

You can now run:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Your Git will send commits `A'`, `B'`, `C'`, and `D'`, and ask their Git, politely, if they'll set *their* `main` to point to `D'`.  Since `D'` extends their branch, they'll say OK.

#### Combining method #3: [run roughshod](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/run%20roughshod) over them

Suppose that, upon looking at their commits, you decide that those commits are utterly worthless.  There's no harm in just throwing them away entirely.

In this case, you can use what Git calls a *force push*, `git push -f` or `git push --force-with-lease`.  The `--force-with-lease` version adds a bit of extra safety (and is generally the way to go) but I won't go into any detail here about what this safety is.

What these options do is tell the other Git, in this case, over at GitHub: *I command you, replace your `main` with my commit hash ID!*  That is, unlike a regular push, it's not a *polite request*.  It's an outright command.  They don't *have to* obey, but if you own that repository, they will.

Obeying your push means that they take your `A-B-C-D` chain (or whatever it is) and make their `main` point to the last commit in this chain, just like your existing `main`.  So if you have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main

G--H   <-- origin/main
```

and you force-push to GitHub (`git push --force-with-lease -u origin main`), they'll set *their* `main` to point to `D`.  You end up with:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- main, origin/main

G--H   ???
```

Commits `G` and `H` appear to vanish.  They'll actually vanish for real from the GitHub repository some time in the future—it's hard to say *when* as that's up to GitHub, but the 30 day rule that works in *your* Git does not apply.  They might go away immediately, or in a day or so.

Because you did get them into your own (local) Git repository, *your* Git will hang on to `G-H` for the at-least-30-days, should you decide that they were valuable after all.  *Finding* them can be tricky though!  We (humans) use names, not hash IDs, for a reason.

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. But still, I have a question regarding this. Previosly GitHub doesn't contain `main` branch in default. But recently, I got to know they have changed their `master` to `main`.

Comment: So, when I create a new repo in GitHub, it automatically create the `main` branch as the default one. Then when we need to push our existing project to that particular GitHub repo, what we basically do is, we initiate git using the `git init` command. Then adding files using `git add <file-name>` and after that `git commit -m "msg"`.

Comment: Then `git remote add origin <URL>` then we use the `git push` command. In my case, I firstly used, `git push -u origin master` command and it didn't work. Actually, I wanted go back to the beginning where this problem occurred and I hope you will have an idea now where I exactly got the problem.

Comment: The thing is, a Git branch *cannot exist* without commits on it. You (or someone) must make *at least one commit* first. After that, an infinite number of branch names can be created: all will identify that single first commit. Once you (or someone, anyone) makes a *second* commit in that Git repository, the potentially-infinite number of branch names can each select one of the *two* commits that exist; and so on.

Comment: This means that for GitHub to create a `main` or `master`, they (GitHub) must first create *at least one commit*. Once this *commit* exists (and has a commit number / hash-ID), *then* they can create a branch named `main` or `master`. You must obtain *this commit* and decide whether you want to keep it and build on it, or throw it away. See the rest of my answer for the rest.

Comment: I just wanted to do is `git branch -m master main` and `git push -u -f origin main`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your local branch is called `master`, whereas the remote branch is called `main`. You have two options:

- Rename your local branch:

  ```
  git checkout master
  git branch -m main
  git push -u origin main
  ```
- Push your local branch to a differently named remote branch:

  ```
  git push -u origin master:main
  ```

Comment: I tried the first option. But still gives the same error.


`git push -u origin main

To https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git

 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/randiltennakoon/my-bmi.git'

hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind

hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.

hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: @RandilTennakoon: your local branch and the remote branch have different commits. "See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details" (either somebody else has already pushed or you are working on a completely different branch)

Comment: git branch > main

git branch -r > origin/main

Comment: I don't have an idea to fix this, any step-by-step guide?

Comment: @RandilTennakoon have you read the "Note about fast-forwards"? It is difficult to give general advice, because I don't know how your local and remote history looks like. But Git's help should provide a good overview

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you just need to commit. Please run the below commands;

**git add .**  (Don't forget the dot at the end)

**git commit -m "initial commit"**

**git push origin main**

Comment: Please let me know, if this doesn't work.

Comment: Please go through the below link as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git