# I am getting erorr in github push origin

Tags: github

when I am typing the command `git push origin master` i am getting an error. What to do?

The error I am getting is

```
error: src refspec main does not match any 
error: failed to push some refs to 'origin'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have forgotten to add remote origin try doing

```
git remote add origin "your-repo-link"
```

After that make some commits and then trying pushing your repo.