# Transfer for branch to anotherRemote/branch except origin remote with Git

Tags: git, github, branch, git-pull, git-remote

I have two remotes. One is origin and the other is another Remote. There is also the url that these two remotes have. My purpose is to transfer the codes from origin / master to test branch in anotherRemote.

My transactions.

```
$ git remote add anotherRemote <anotherRemote-url>
$ git remote -v
$ anotherRemote   <anotherRemote-url> (fetch)
$ anotherRemote   <anotherRemote-url> (push)
$ origin          <origin-url> (fetch)
$ origin          <origin-url> (push)
$ git fetch anotherRemote
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "initial commit"
$ git push anotherRemote testBranch
```

but i get the following error

```
error: src refspec testBranch does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to '<anotherRemote-url>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command:

> ```
> git push anotherRemote testBranch
> ```

is short for:

```
git push anotherRemote testBranch:testBranch
```

That is, your Git will:

1. Look up the left hand side of `testBranch:testBranch` to find a commit hash ID.
2. Assuming step 1 works, contact the Git that answers at the URL stored under the name `anotherRemote` and send the commit(s) that go with that hash ID.
3. Assuming step 2 works, ask that other Git to set *its* branch name `testBranch` to the commit hash ID found in step 1.

But you don't *have* a branch named `testBranch`, so step 1 simply fails.  (You could *create* this branch name, but you do not have to do so.)

> My purpose is to transfer the codes from `origin/master` to test branch in anotherRemote.

The name `origin/master`, in your own Git repository, is a way for your Git to find the hash ID of the a particular commit.<sup>1</sup>  This name is usable on the left side of the `source:destination` syntax for `git push`.  There is one small glitch though.  You might therefore wish to use:

```
git push anotherRemote origin/master:refs/heads/testBranch
```

This invokes the same three-step process above, but instead of trying to find the name `testBranch` in your own repository, it uses the name `origin/master` in your own repository to find the correct commit hash ID.

Note that the *right hand side* is now `refs/heads/testBranch` instead of just `testBranch`.  This is the full spelling of the branch name `testBranch`.  The reason we now have to use the *full spelling*, instead of the simple abbreviation, is that `git push` no longer knows that we want to work with *branch* names.  We could, for instance, mean to ask the Git over at `anotherRemote` to create a *tag* name.

Using the full spelling like this tells our Git that we want it to ask the other Git to create a *branch* name.  Without this, we get the following:

```
$ git push origin origin/xyz:newbranch
error: The destination you provided is not a full refname (i.e.,
starting with "refs/"). We tried to guess what you meant by:

- Looking for a ref that matches 'newbranch' on the remote side.
- Checking if the <src> being pushed ('refs/remotes/origin/xyz')
  is a ref in "refs/{heads,tags}/". If so we add a corresponding
  refs/{heads,tags}/ prefix on the remote side.

Neither worked, so we gave up. You must fully qualify the ref.
hint: The <src> part of the refspec is a commit object.
hint: Did you mean to create a new branch by pushing to
hint: 'refs/remotes/origin/xyz:refs/heads/newbranch'?
error: failed to push some refs to <url>
```

This very long error message is Git's way of saying: *please use `refs/heads/newbranch` here*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The commit hash ID your Git finds here depends on the *last time you had your Git talk to the Git at `origin`*.  When you run `git fetch origin`, your Git calls up their Git.  Their Git lists out their branch names and the commit hash IDs that go with each name.  Your Git then gets those commits, if you don't already have them, and then updates your `origin/*` names based on their *branch* names.

The fact that your Git updates your `origin/master` (remote-tracking name) based on *their* `master` (branch name) is why many people call these *remote-tracking branch names*.  They're not *branch* names, though.  *Branch* names start with `refs/heads/` internally, and these remote-tracking names have a full spelling that starts with `refs/remotes/`.  That is, your `master` branch is short for `refs/heads/master`, for instance; your `origin/master` is short for `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

When you run `git branch -r`, your Git displays your remote-tracking names with `refs/remotes/` stripped off the front.  When you run `git branch -r`, your Git displays your remote-tracking names with only `refs/` stripped off the front, so that you will see `remotes/origin/master` instead of `origin/master`.  The *full name* is still `refs/remotes/origin/master`: what has changed is how much of this boring full name Git took off to make the name seem more exciting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I pushed an existing Git Repository. It's a problem caused by my fault. But I also learned new things here. Thanks.
Problem solved. I tried your suggestions. It works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
git push <remote> <local_branch>:<remote_name>
```

Which in your case would be:

```
$ git push anotherRemote HEAD:testBranch
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4183856/15840659) for more details

Comment: This only works right if `HEAD` resolves to the right commit hash ID. That may or may not be the case at the time the OP runs this `git push` command.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I pushed an existing Git Repository. It's a problem caused by my fault. But I also learned new things here.