# Create a repo from an existing project

Tags: git, gitlab

Can someone tell me how to solve this: When I execute `git init` I only see (master) not (master->origin) and, when I do git branch, it returns nothing and when I try to push I get this error:

```
git push -u origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:BghAek/something.git'
```

Comment: When you say "existing project", do you mean that this code has never been committed to a git repo before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572252/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 2):

After `git init`, you need to commit the code with `git add .` and then `git commit -m "Initial commit"`. Then you will be able to `git push` if your repository has a remote that points to GitHub or some other online service.

I strongly encourage you to learn the basics of git. [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is a good place to start. The first three chapters explains the fundamental concepts that you will use regularly. The remaining chapters get into more advanced concepts if you need them later.

Comment: You won the race this time!

Comment: thanks for your respect.... now I do all what you say but when I write  git push origin master or  git push -u origin master it tell me     error: the requested upstream branch 'origin' does not exist . what i do ?

Comment: @عمروالقيران The next step is to add your GitHub repo as a remote. You can do this with the `git remote` command. You can do `git help remote` to get more info about it.

Answer (score 1):

In order to push from your new local repository, you need to:

- make sure you have an *empty* newly created GitHub repository
- rename your local branch from master to main (check your Git version): `git branch -m master main`
- execute `git config --global init.defaultbranch main` to use main from now on for any new local repository (since GitHub is also using `main` by default)
- add the remote GitHub repository URL as remote origin:
  `git remote add origin https://github.com/<me>/<myNewRepo>`
- finally push: `git push -u origin main`

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me and I really appreciate it