# Cannot push to repository on Github: "error: src refspec main does not match any"

Tags: git

I am trying to push my index.html project to my GitHub. I created my repo but, when I run the following commands on my terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sites\kodluyoruz-frontend> git remote origin
PS C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sites\kodluyoruz-frontend> git push -u origin main
```

I am getting this error:

```
error: src refspec main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://https://github.com/alpino87/-lk-Html-Sayfam'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/git-message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

This error message can occur in git if your remote repo does not exist. Double-check the name of your GitHub repository URL and then run the following command:

```
git remote set-url origin <new-url>
```

Then you can try your `git push -u origin main` command again and it should work

Comment: Thank you, but then I got this error =)))) error: No such remote 'origin'
PS C:\Users\pc\Documents\Sites\kodluyoruz-frontend>

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations**:

- The remote url mentioned in your first error is `https://https://github.com/alpino87/-lk-Html-Sayfam`. That is incorrect. Not only is there a double `https://`. The username mentioned also does not exist on github.
- Your second error in the comments of @daniel-arthur indicates that the remote is missing entirely.
- The `refspec main does not match` could indicate that you have not yet committed your files. If so, add some files `git add .` and commit them `git commit -m 'some message'` before pushing.

**Debugging**:

I would follow the following steps to debug your issue:

1. Check what branches you have locally and thus **can** push via `git branch`. Based on your example, you should have a `main` branch.
2. See if you have a valid remote called origin: `git remote -v`

Possible causes of error:

1. You don't have a branch called `main`. To fix this, create this branch from your currently checked out branch via `git checkout -b main`.
2. You don't have a remote called `origin`. To fix this, create a new remote via `git remote add origin <url of origin remote>`
3. You have a remote called origin, but it is wrong. To fix this, you can remove the old origin and re-add the correct one as described at (2). To remove: `git remote rm origin`.

After above fixes, you should be good to push your `main` branch to your remote called `origin` via `git push -u origin main`.

For reference, see: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories