# error: src refspec main does not match any

Tags: git, github

I have a local branch named *master* and its upstream is set to *origin/main*

But whenever I push to remote repo using `git push -u origin main` it shows error:

> error: src refspec main does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to

But it works fine when I use `git push -u origin HEAD:main`

So what's the Problem in here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/git-message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git push origin main` means "*push **local** branch `main`*" and you don't have local branch `main`, you have `master`. After the first `git push -u origin master:main` you should push using `git push origin` or even bare `git push`. Or continue pushing using `git push origin master:main`

Comment: ... or rename the local `master` to `main`, or ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

This error appears when the branch you are trying to push your local repository does not exist.

"error: src refspec main does not match any" - Means, no branch called "main" was found in the source.

So, Make a branch like this:

```
git push --set-upstream origin [branch name]
```

In this case:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

This will create a branch called "master" and will push changes to that branch.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following commands. It would change the origin

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

- then Verify remote URL is correct:

```
git remote -v
```

- then Push to repo

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: This does not address the question, which was about a main/master branch name mismatch, not about the URL for origin.