# Deploying Django App to Heroku Fail to Push

Tags: django, heroku, command

I am trying to deploy my app to heroku and am running into errors. I'm directly following the walkthrough on Heroku's site, with no luck.

error:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to
```

cmd line:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oAKk.jpg

Any thoughts?

Comment: do check once again if your git's default branch name is "master"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git)