# "git push origin master" without making any commits yet results in "error: src refspec master does not match any"

Tags: git

I have created a git repository locally, as shown below

```
doudo@LAPTOP-P5H3MDKN MINGW64 /d/software/java/java_work/DataStruct/DataStructureAndAlgorithm (master)
$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:douzhenjun/DataStruct.git'

doudo@LAPTOP-P5H3MDKN MINGW64 /d/software/java/java_work/DataStruct/DataStructureAndAlgorithm (master)
$ git branch

doudo@LAPTOP-P5H3MDKN MINGW64 /d/software/java/java_work/DataStruct/DataStructureAndAlgorithm (master)
$ git push --set-upstream origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:douzhenjun/DataStruct.git'
```

I have added remote orgin repository on github,

but when I attempt to push cotents to remote origin, fatals above occurs. Moreover, I have built a new branch named dou and ever switched to it, but I can't switch again to master. This branch(named master) is what I rebuilt, when I key in command git branch, there is nothing to see. Why is it ?

```
doudo@LAPTOP-P5H3MDKN MINGW64 /d/software/java/java_work/DataStruct/DataStructureAndAlgorithm (master)
$ ll -a
total 29
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Apr 20 13:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Apr 16  2021 ../
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Apr 20 20:26 .git/
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Apr  4 14:21 .idea/
-rw-r--r-- 1 doudo 197121 455 Jun 22  2020 DataStructureAndAlgorithm.iml
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Aug 30  2020 out/
drwxr-xr-x 1 doudo 197121   0 Apr 19 21:05 src/
```

[my remote repository on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2caO.png)

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: `git push --set-upstream origin master`

Comment: probably a duplicate of [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181861/1256452) (but I'll wait until the question gets revised)

Answer (score 1):

Git is about *commits*, not branches.

"but I can't switch again to master" Because it doesn't exist. You never did an add and *commit* on `master` so it was an "unborn" branch.

Therefore you can't push it (you never made any *commits* to push) and your `git branch` output is empty (you have no branches); and having switched to a different branch you can't switch back (there is nothing to go back to).

If you truly have a `dou` branch with commits, you could now *rename* it `master` and push it. But you have not proved that you do.

But it would be better at this point to forget `master` because your main branch at GitHub is called `main`. You might want to read my article https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/.

Answer (score -1):

First make sure your SSH key has been configured correctly, then certify that you have your remote repo configured with

```
echo "remote name: $(git remote)" "URL: $(git remote get-url $(git remote))"
```

this must show your repo "nickname" and repo-URL like this:

```
remote name: origin
URL: git@github.com:douzhenjun/repo_name.git
```

Then with the command `git push --set-upstream origin master` you configure the branch master in your remote repo as the "target" for push. And with `git push -u origin master` you can speciy what remote repo and branch are you pushing into.

Note that `origin` is the name configured when you run the command `git remote add {name} {URL}`, the command `git remote` print this name.

Remember to commit all local changes before you push to remote content, an basic "workflow" of git is `pull -> commits -> push`

Before edit run `git pull`, this will update your local repo with remote content, then after you finish your modifications you will commit your modifications, then push to remote content.