# GitHub pushes to Master no Main Branch

Tags: github

Pretty beginner question, but I didn't find the answer, I did my account into GitHub account, there are two branches: Main and Master, I tried to do push first to 'main' so later to 'master', after commit, the error:

Both branches exist:

[image]

The error:

[image]

Comment: Try updating your default branch to `master`: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Comment: @bicarlsen Didn't work.

Comment: Dang. Perhaps One of these links will help: [refspec does not match any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git), [track a remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch).