# Git GitHub cannot push; how to fix?

Tags: git, github

In GitHub, by mistake, I created a repository
https://github.com/myidmyrepo.git (incorrect instead of)
https://github.com/myid/myrepo.git (correct).

1. I do not see the incorrect repo in GitHub, so I cannot delete it.
2. Now, I created https://github.com/myid/myrepo.git (correct)
   but
   *git push --set-upstream origin master*
   **remote: Not Found
   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myidmyrepo.git/' not found**

*git push -u origin master*
**error: src refspec maste does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myidmyrepo.git'**

Please, help.

Comment: Remove the remote and add the correct one https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: @Andrew No need to remove it — just change the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the following command:

`git remote set-url origin "https://github.com/myid/myrepo.git"`

This command changes the remote origin URL to the correct one. Then, you can push your work normally.

Answer (score 0):

You've described two different error messages, and the differences between them are important:

> ```
> git push --set-upstream origin master
> remote: Not Found
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/myidmyrepo.git/' not found
> ```

This error is due to having the wrong URL stored under the name `origin`.

To fix that, use `git remote set-url origin` as shown in [Moemen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73185809/1256452), or use `git config --edit` to edit `.git/config` in your favorite text editor—make sure it's one that won't damage a Git configuration—to correct the URL stored under the remote name `origin`.

> ```
> git push -u origin master
> error: src refspec master does not match any
> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myidmyrepo.git'
> ```

This error is different (though it still has the wrong URL) as it says `src refspec master does not match any`.  This is a duplicate of many previous questions, including [Message 'src refspec master does not match any' when pushing commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181861/1256452).  The message itself simply means that you have nothing named `master`, either because you're using some other branch name, or because you have no commits yet, or both.