# Unable to push branch after commit

Tags: git, git-refspec

my push / pull options are not highlighted after i commited my change in RSTudio, why?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrbZX.png)

If I do git push -u origin master, I get

```
error: src refspec master does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https:/...
```

My Github desktop shows this btw -
[github desktop screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeFrs.png)

Comment: Seems to be the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181861/message-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any-when-pushing-commits-in-git

Comment: Note that you're not on a branch named `master`. You are on a branch named `develop`. What made you believe you should run `git push -u origin master` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

check if the local repo is connected to the remote repo (git remote origin ....). then check the email you are using to push if it is connected to the repo as well git config user.email