# I've lost both my master branch and according to GIT, my HEAD (though I could have told it that). How do I get them back?

Tags: git

I'm not entirely sure of the steps that caused this however I have ended up without my GIT master branch.

I had a crack at fixing things using the instructions here: http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/detached-head.html however my general ignorance of GIT may have left me in a worse pickle than I started out.

```
$ git branch
  first-cucumber-attempt
  notifications
* second-cucumber-attempt
  sendgrid-setup
```

At some point I apparently started working on a detached HEAD and now I don't know how to find my master (I feel a little like Alice right now).

Attempting to checkout master gives:

```
$ git checkout master
  error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Attempting to pull master gives:

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:petenixey/kind-advice
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

The branch, "second_cucumber_attempt" has all of the code I want to merge into master and master is still safe on github but I can't get to it. I am thoroughly stuck.

Comment: +1 for "I feel a little like Alice right now."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The "master" in `git checkout master` is supposed to be a branch, which you do not have.  You can checkout the remote's master and make it your own with `git checkout origin/master -b master`, which should also set it up as a "tracking branch".

You can see your list of remote branches with `git branch -r`.

Comment: I hit a subsequent problem when trying to push the repository up to github (error: src refspec remote does not match any.) however that was solved by this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959477/error-when-git-push-to-github