# git push a sub branch

Tags: git, branch

I was in branch `feature_swap` there I did some change but I am not confident enough to push those changes in `feature_swap` branch. So I *tried* to create another sub branch `feature_swap_experiment` with

```
git branch feature_swap_experiment
git checkout feature_swap_experiment
```

Now I want to push to `feature_swap_experiment` I've tried 
`git push origin feature_swap_experiment` which is not working

```
error: src refspec feature_swap_experiment does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://uname@bitbucket.org/uname/project.git'
```

Comment: Your error message seems a bit truncated.  Was there anything after "any" ?

Comment: I added the last line too now. in edit

Answer (score 0):

```
git push origin feature_swap_experiment
```

should be the right command. Is there any chance that your remote is not set up correctly?

1. if you check master back out, can you push to the remote?
2. Do the contents of your .git/config file look correct?  Especially check the [remote "origin"] section of the file.

Also, `git branch -a` should give you a list of all branches, local and remote, so you should be able to quickly see if things are set up correctly.

This may help:
[How do you create a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519006/git-how-to-create-remote-branch)

Edit:  After looking at the error message you added to the question, it seems like you might have the same problem as described here:  [Error when "git push" to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959477/error-when-git-push-to-github)

So in your case, you would run:

```
git push https://uname@bitbucket.org/uname/project.git  HEAD:feature_swap_experiment
```

Comment: My project is on bitbucket. What should I put in <remote-name>

Comment: git push feature_swap_experimental will not work, where is the remote?

Comment: When you don't specify a remote branch name, git assumes that the remote and local branches have the same name.  Therefore, if you want to keep the name consistent across repositories, don't specify the remote branch.

Comment: My project is in bitbucket. How to check whether my remote is checked properly or not ?

Comment: @DiproSen : just edited my answer in response to you.  Hope this suggestio helps.