# Why can't I push my new branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I made a new branch, checked it out and made a commit:

```
git branch my-branch [HASH]
git checkout my-branch
git commit -am "Add some stuff to my new branch"
```

However, I can't push it to github. `git push origin my-branch` returns:

```
error: src refspec branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Me/my-project.git'
```

`git show-refs` looks like this:

```
[HASH] refs/heads/my-branch
[HASH] refs/heads/master
[HASH] refs/heads/some-branch
[HASH] refs/remotes/origin/master
[HASH] refs/remotes/origin/some-branch
[HASH] refs/stash
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Tried push -u origin my-branch ?

Comment: @fatfredyy Same error message

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959477/error-when-git-push-to-github ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The branch doesn't exist on github, when you push git checks the refs of origin for your branch and doesn't find it.

Add the branch as a remote branch:

**git 1.8.x**

```
git branch -u origin/my-branch my-branch
```

**git 1.7.x**

```
git branch --set-upstream my-branch origin/my-branch
```

Now you can push.

Answer (score 14):

Here is the command you would execute to push all of the changes from your local branch ("my-branch") to a "my-branch" branch on the GitHub repository:

```
git push -u origin my-branch
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are tired of writing up the branch name, use this neat shorthand command.

```
git push origin HEAD -u
```

This basically says: push whatever branch I am currently on to origin and set it as it's upstream (remote tracking branch).

Comment: This seems like the easiest way since you don't have to explicitly name the branch. I just did it without the `-u` (e.g. `git push origin HEAD`) and it seems to have worked fine. Do you know what the difference would be?

Comment: OK, the local was not tracking the remote until I used the `-u`, then I could actually do a `push`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in command line parsing. As you can see in this message:

```
error: src refspec branch does not match any.
```

git tries to push a branch with the name `branch`, not `my-branch`. What OS/shell are you running? Maybe try

```
git push origin "my-branch"
```