# git: error: src refspec master does not match any

Tags: git

After cloning git repository to directory "hggit" and setting the remote origin with

```
mbm:hggit my name$ git remote add origin git@code.getpantheon.com:"mystringhere"
```

After editing files I committed the changes (while located in a sub-dir) with

```
mbm:handelgroup michaelmausler$ git commit -m "first commit"
[master 5a29bc8] first commit
 1 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

I then attempted to push file changes and received the following error

```
mbm:hggit myname$ git push origin master
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@code.getpantheon.com:"mystringhere"'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you've got a ref called "master". Try running "git show-ref" to see what refs you do have. Perhaps the branch you mean is called something else.

Comment: i did  "git remote add origin" should i have done "git remote add master" instead?

Comment: That was probably the right thing to do. What you need to verify is that the branch named "master" exists on the remote named "origin", that branch exists in your local repository, and that you've committed to that branch. Try running gitk.

Comment: i cloned it so the branch does exist

Comment: When you run "git status" what does it say?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If `git status` does indicate that you do have an active master branch (since you did make a first commit after all), check if you made any typo when defining your remote: see "[Push origin master error on new repository](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10080621/6309)":

```
git remote rm origin
```

> Then I recreated the origin, making sure the name of my origin was typed EXACTLY the same way my origin was spelled.

```
git remote add origin git@....
```

You can simplify with:

```
git remote set-url origin git@....
```

Then you can establish a tracking link between the local branch and the remote tracking branch:

```
git push -u origin master
```

You can also push it to a different branch on origin:

```
git push -u origin master:anotherBranch
```

Answer (score 17):

use git branch -m to rename your local repository to have the same name you want to push to the remote

Answer (score 8):

You need to make sure that the branch name is the same locally and remotely. So it's not enough to have `master` branch on remote. You also need this branch locally.