# "src refspec does not match" and "failed to push some refs" errors on git push

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-remote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error when “git push” to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959477/error-when-git-push-to-github)

I tried to push my new branch (let's just call it `new_branch`) to remote rep. There is no such branch there yet, but `git push origin new_branch:new_branch` should create it. When I try to do it, this is what I get:

```
error: src refspec new_branch does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@***'
```

I dug through million of questions like this on SO, but none of them specified these two errors at once and they referred only to `master` branch (I don't know if it makes any difference).

What I already tried include `commit`, `reset` and `push` in many configurations. And they didn't work so far. I suppose there may be some issue with `HEAD`, because I messed with it some time ago. But it's a guess and I don't even know how to check it properly, since GIT is still a *teeny-tiny* mystery for me.

So - how can I get rid of these errors and push my local branch to remote repository?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827351/push-origin-master-error-on-new-repository, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568641/git-error-src-refspec-master-does-not-match-any, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959477/error-when-git-push-to-github

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The syntax you're using for `git push` includes a *refspec* (`new_branch:new_branch`).  Refspecs are always in the form `source:destination`, so the error is telling you that something's wrong with the source part of your refspec.

I was able to reproduce this error by trying to push a branch that doesn't exist (`git push origin fake:fake`).  I know this seems like a painfully stupid question, but are you sure you're spelling your branch name correctly?  Keep in mind that branch names are case-sensitive.  What do you see when you type `git branch`?

Comment: As I read this: "Of course I spelled the branch name right..." 5 seconds later: "Oops. Works now!"

Comment: Heh.  I've so been there, Jonathan!

Comment: "so the error is telling you that something's wrong with the source part of your refspec"

That's it. Forgot to commit :)

Comment: @EthanBrown so if i have understood it correctly, suppose i don't have any branch named `fake` on remote repo but have one created in the local repo. So what this command `git push origin fake:fake` actually does it create a `fake` branch on remote and push all the commits of local `fake` to this remote `fake` branch. Right ?

Comment: That's correct, @humbleCodes.  Also, you can use `get push origin :fake` to _delete_ a branch from the remote, which I've always found to be a little...obscure.  There are lots of syntax choices in Git that I find a little questionable but hey, we get used to the dominant system!