# Push to branch on GitHub given branch url

Tags: git, github, branch, push

As a git beginner, I am having the worst time with this. If this question was asked before, then I apologize--but I cannot find any Stack Overflow page that gives me the answer I need. That being said, here is my question:

What are **all** the steps required to locally push to a branch on GitHub given the branch url? Specifically, how do you make the repo point at the correct location after initialization?

So far I have tried:

```
git init
git remote add <branch_name> <url_of_branch>
git add .
git commit -m "Message"
git push origin <branch_name>
```

Along with numerous other attempts. The error message I have been getting is:

```
error: src refspec <branch_name> does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:<username>/path/to/rep
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably you are running into this same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201083/src-refspec-does-not-match-and-failed-to-push-some-refs-errors-on-git-push

Comment: You're adding a remote, not a branch

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the local branch first (instead of `git remote`):

```
git checkout -b <branch_name>
```

Then add, commit and push while setting an **[upstream branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6244487/6309)**:

```
git push -u origin <branch_name>
```

Confirm with `git branch -avv` to see both your local branch and its upstream [remote tracking branch](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/#Tracking_Branches_and_Remote_Tracking_Branches_Summary) `origin/<branch_name>`